# Convert DOS/Windows line endings to Linux line endings in Vim

Tags: file, vim, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

If I open files I created in Windows, the lines all end with `^M`.
How do I delete these characters all at once?

Comment: If you do a `hexdump -C badfile` and see `0x0d 0x0a` `"\r\n"` that is your problem.

Comment: Worth comparing with -
[What is `^M` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32001)

Answer (score 1216, accepted):

[dos2unix](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix) is a commandline utility that will do this.

In Vim, `:%s/^M//g` will if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> to input the ^M (On Windows, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-m</kbd> instead).

Vim may not show the `^M` characters if the file is loaded with a `dos` (Windows) file format. In this case you can `:set ff=unix` and then save the file with `:w` or `:w!` and Vim will reformat the file as it saves it for you.

There is documentation on the [fileformat](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/options.html#%27fileformat%27) setting, and the Vim wiki has a comprehensive [page on line ending conversions](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_end-of-line_format_for_dos-mac-unix).

Alternately, if you move files back and forth a lot, you might not want to convert them, but rather to do `:set ff=dos`, so Vim will know it's a DOS file and use DOS conventions for line endings.

Comment: That was it for me thank you pal :> Bash wouldn't launch the script because of line endings. Stupid notepad really...

Comment: `:%s/^M//g` should be `:%s/\r//g`, because `^M` just means "match capital "M" at the beginning of the line".

Comment: Not if you do as the answer says and 'use ctrl-v ctrl-m to input the ^M'.

Comment: **crtl-v** is no good, on windows it pastes clipboard contents to the command line. Solution `:%s/\r//g` worked for me, cheers @Bunyk

Comment: I got confused when I tried this, because it seemed to take ages to do the conversion, when in fact it was just waiting for user input.

Comment: @ropata What you want on Windows is [**ctrl-q**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/426910/1028230).

Comment: dos2unix might be the better solution but only if it's present on the system.  I don't think we should lead the answer with it. `set ff=unix` seems the best answer.

Comment: I must be missing something, because `set ff=unix` does nothing. Maybe it converts the file, but all of the `^M` characters are still there.

Comment: If you want to ensure you keep the new lines its best to actually do this :%s/\r/\r/g   unix/vim will put in the right newline char with the replace \r

Comment: both `^M` (Ctrl+V Ctrl+M) and `\r` are not found in my file but I definitely see them in diff (VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4)

Comment: `:%s/\r//g`  or `:%s/^M//g` does not work. `:set ff=unix ` is work as desired. But It formats whole file, Not only those lines which contain ^m

Comment: There is good [source](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux) for change or convert to and from Windows to UNIX.

Comment: @felwithe - :set ff=unix then you :wq the file to write out the new format.  I just did this two minutes ago to clean a file I got from a developer.

Comment: Use the vim set command to show the file format `:set ff?`. The command returns fileformat=<dos/unix/mac> to indect current file format.

Comment: when you run :set ff=unix you still need to write the changes to the file with :w or :x

Comment: @mwfearnley I agree that `:set ff=unix` is the best, but although I now have edit privileges, that seems like an edit to leave to the original answer's discretion.

Answer (score 333):

Change the line endings in the view:

```
:e ++ff=dos
:e ++ff=mac
:e ++ff=unix
```

This can also be used as saving operation (:w alone will not save using the line endings you see on screen):

```
:w ++ff=dos
:w ++ff=mac
:w ++ff=unix
```

And you can use it from the command-line:

```
for file in *.cpp
do 
    vi +':w ++ff=unix' +':q' "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried vi +':wq ++ff=unix' <filepath> for a lazy one like me.

Comment: This should be the most upvoted answer. `:w +ff=unix` is so much nicer than most of the other stuff written here, and the bash script is a nice bonus.

Comment: The `:e` commands don't appear to do anything on my Windows vim install.  My view still shows the `^M` codes.

Comment: I read the `:e ++ff=unix` everywhere but the simplest for me that worked is `:w ++ff=unix` then quit & reopen file.

Comment: @OlivierPons but :e does the same thing as reopening the file? How is adding more unnecessary steps to your solution making it simpler?

Comment: Well changing the line ending in the view does not do what he asked, which is removing the ^M.

Answer (score 177):

I typically use

```
:%s/\r/\r/g
```

which seems a little odd, but works because of the way that Vim matches linefeeds. I also find it easier to remember :)

Comment: This works consistently across platforms. The best answer here.

Comment: I've never had any problem with `:set ff=unix` before, but the file I opened today must have been particularly weird. Vim said it was already `fileformat=unix` but all the line endings were `^M`. This solution worked for me.

Comment: This solution adds unwanted extra lines for me, doubling the number of lines in the file. `:%s/\r//g` instead works for me.

Comment: Victor, your files likely have \r\n endings. the \r isn't read as a newline but the \n is.  In the files I'm running into are \r and you have to add a newline character.

Comment: astyle, dos2unix, vim fileformat, notepad, ultra-edit, etc. all didn't work; this did!  Previous to trying this I had to open the file in Wordpad, paste into notepad and then paste into ultraedit before I could go back to VIM.  Someone put varying types of linefeed types and EOF in files which then made it hard to find where function calls were in sources.  grep returned junk for the file with mixed linefeed types and EOF.  Disappointed that other methods didn't work.  Thanks for a simple solution!

Comment: I tried the other solutions here, but this is the only one that worked for me. I had imported a CSV file into Excel (Mac OS X), and after transforming it a bit, exported it as a CSV. It ended up being a one-line file with `^M` separating what were the original lines.

Comment: I’m not vim-ish enough to understand why, but this solution works for me in circumstances where the accepted answer failed

Comment: When you do a `hexdump -C badfile` you can see the hex sequence `0x0d 0x0a` which is your problem.

Comment: @VictorZamanian's `:%s/\r//g` is the *only* general-purpose solution – especially for mixed-mode files containing a heterogeneous admixture of both DOS- and UNIX-style newlines. The canonical solutions (e.g., `:set ff=unix`, `:e ++ff=unix`) assume every line of the current buffer ends in the same newline style. Sometimes they do; sometimes they don't. *Cue sadface.*

Comment: @VictorZamanian's, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65125795/7676971) method should help solve the problem with adding new lines.

Comment: @VictorS. ? I didn't have a problem adding newlines. I got extra newlines I *didn't* want. And if you read my comment to the end you'll see I had a solution already. Thanks though.

Answer (score 141):

I prefer to use the following command:

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

You can also use `mac` or `dos` to respectively convert your file to Mac or MS-DOS/Windows file convention. And it does nothing if the file is already in the correct format.

For more information, see the Vim help:

```
:help fileformat
```

Comment: This command doesn't appear to do anything on my Windows vim.  My view still has `^M` chars in it.

Comment: Adding `set fileformat=unix` to my .vimrc file worked.

Answer (score 23):

`:set fileformat=unix` to convert from DOS to Unix.

Comment: This actually resolved the issue for me. I wasn't able to find those characters while searching.

Answer (score 23):

In VIM:

```
:e ++ff=dos | set ff=unix | w!
```

In shell with VIM:

```
vim some_file.txt +'e ++ff=dos | set ff=unix | wq!'
```

`e ++ff=dos` - force open file in `dos` format.

`set ff=unix` - convert file to `unix` format.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to convert a file to the wrong format and couldn't use Git to undo it. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 20):

```
:%s/\r\+//g
```

In Vim, that strips all carriage returns, and leaves only newlines.

Comment: For some reason above didn't work for me under windows gvim. But when changed to `:%s/\r//g` it worked like a charm.

Comment: @soltysh :%s/\r\+$//g

Answer (score 15):

From: [File format](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_end-of-line_format_for_dos-mac-unix)

[Esc] :%s/\r$//

Comment: +1 for pointing to the official doc site. For anyone using the above link, see the section "Converting the current file" on that page.

Comment: This + vim -b <filename> worked like a charm, thanks, +1

Comment: The link is half-broken. It redirects to another page.

Answer (score 10):

```
tr -d '\15\32' < winfile.txt > unixfile.txt
```

(See: *[Convert between Unix and Windows text files](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acux.html)*)

Comment: That seems to be a more universal answer; it works for me on FreeBSD out of the box (on that machine, vi seems to be truly ancient version...). Yes, vim is also installed on that machine; I should have tried that...whatever.

Answer (score 10):

To run directly in a Linux console:

```
vim file.txt +"set ff=unix" +wq
```

Answer (score 9):

## Convert directory of files from DOS to Unix

#### Using command line and sed, find all files in current directory with the extension ".ext" and remove all "^M"

*@ https://gist.github.com/sparkida/7773170*

```
find $(pwd) -type f -name "*.ext" | while read file; do sed -e 's/^M//g' -i "$file"; done;
```

Also, as mentioned in a previous answer, **^M** = <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> (don't just type the caret "^" symbol and M).

Answer (score 8):

`dos2unix` can directly modify the file contents.

You can directly use it on the file, without any need for temporary file redirection.

```
dos2unix input.txt input.txt
```

The above uses the assumed US keyboard. Use the `-437` option to use the UK keyboard.

```
dos2unix -437 input.txt input.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

The following steps can convert the file format for DOS to Unix:

```
:e ++ff=dos     Edit file again, using dos file format ('fileformats' is ignored).[A 1]
:setlocal ff=unix     This buffer will use LF-only line endings when written.[A 2]
:w     Write buffer using Unix (LF-only) line endings.
```

Reference: *[File format](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_end-of-line_format_for_dos-mac-unix)*

Comment: The link is half-broken. It redirects to another page.

Answer (score 6):

I found a very easy way: Open the file with [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano): `nano file.txt`

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save, but before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, press: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to toggle between DOS and Unix/Linux line-endings, or: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to toggle between Mac and Unix/Linux line-endings, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to quit.

Comment: done this on a linux server, the file had `^M` endings. save as dos to keep, save as linux to remove. can check using `cat -v`

Comment: This question is about vim, not nano.

Answer (score 5):

With the following command:

```
:%s/^M$//g
```

To get the `^M` to appear, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> tells Vim to take the next character entered literally.

Answer (score 5):

The comment about getting the ^M to appear is what worked for me. Merely typing "^M" in my vi got nothing (not found). The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> sequence did it perfectly though.

My working substitution command was

```
:%s/Ctrl-V Ctrl-M/\r/g
```

and it looked like this on my screen:

```
:%s/^M/\r/g
```

Answer (score 4):

```
:g/Ctrl-v Ctrl-m/s///
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> is the character `\r`, or carriage return, which DOS line endings add. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> tells Vim to insert a literal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> character at the command line.

Taken as a whole, this command replaces all `\r` with nothing, removing them from the ends of lines.

Comment: Elaborated in [Dannid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/convert-dos-line-endings-to-linux-line-endings-in-vim/11475637#11475637).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command:
`:%s/^V^M//g`

 where the '^' means use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
vim somefile.txt +"%s/\r/\r/g" +wq
```

Or the [dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) utility.

Answer (score 2):

In Vim, type:

```
:w !dos2unix %
```

This will pipe the contents of your current buffer to the [dos2unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) command and write the results over the current contents. Vim will ask to reload the file after.

Answer (score 1):

The below command is used for reformating all .sh file in the current directory. I tested it on my [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) OS.

```
for file in *.sh; do awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' $file >luxubutmp; cp -f luxubutmp $file; rm -f luxubutmp ;done
```

Answer (score 0):

From Wikia:

```
%s/\r\+$//g
```

That will find all carriage return signs (one and more reps) up to the end of line and delete, so just `\n` will stay at EOL.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way. I opened a file in DOS EOL and when I save the file, that will automatically convert to Unix EOL:

```
autocmd BufWrite * :set ff=unix
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted newlines in place of the ^M's. Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/\x0d/\n/g' excel_created.txt
```

Or to write to stdout:

```
perl -p -e 's/\x0d/\n/g' < excel_created.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I knew I'd seen this somewhere. Here is the [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) login tip:

Do you need to remove all those ^M characters from a DOS file? Try

```
tr -d \\r < dosfile > newfile
    -- Originally by Dru <genesis@istar.ca>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more than you asked for but:

```
nmap <C-d> :call range(line('w0'),line('w$'))->map({_,v-> getline(v)})->map({_,v->trim(v,join(map(range(1,0x1F)+[0xa0],{n->n->nr2char()}),''),2)})->map({k,v->setline(k+1,v)})<CR>
```

Run this and `:set ff=unix|dos` and no more need for unix2dos.

- the single arg form of trim() has the same default mask above, plus **0X20** (an actual space) instead of **0x1F**
- that default mask clears out all non-printing chars including non-breaking spaces **[0xa0]** that are hard to find
- create a list of lines from the range of lines
- map that list to the trim function with using the same mask code as the source, less spaces
- map that again to setline to replace the lines.
- all `:set fileformat=` does at this point is choose which eol to save it with, dos or unix
- it should be pretty easy to change the range of characters above if you want to eliminate or add some

Answer (score 0):

To delete these `DOS/Windows` line endings characters all at once, regardless of where they occur in a line (this is not a good idea if two lines were separated only by a `CR` because the command joins the lines together):

```
:%s/\r//g
```

Reference: [File format -> 6.Removing unwanted CR or LF characters](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/File_format#Removing_unwanted_CR_or_LF_characters).

But, You could choose to convert these `DOS/Windows` line endings into `Unix`.

That means, to convert the current file from any mixture of `CRLF/LF-only` line endings, so all lines end with `LF` only:

```
:update              Save any changes. 
:e ++ff=dos          Edit file again, using dos file format ('fileformats' is ignored).
:setlocal ff=unix    This buffer will use LF-only line endings when written.
:w                   Write buffer using unix (LF-only) line endings.
```

Reference: [File format -> 3.Converting the current file](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/File_format#Converting_the_current_file).

In the above, replacing `:set ff=unix` with `:set ff=mac` would write the file with mac (`CR-only`) line endings. Or, if it was a mac file to start with, you would use `:e ++ff=mac` to read the file correctly, so you could convert the line endings to `unix` or `dos`.

More reference:

1.[Configure line separators -> Change line separators for the current file(IntelliJ IDEA)﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html#change_line_ending).

2.[Configure line separators -> Configure line separators for new files(IntelliJ IDEA)﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html#separator_settings).

3.[Vim Tips Wiki -> File format](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/File_format#Converting_the_current_file).

Answer (score -1):

Usually there is a `dos2unix` command you can use for this. Just make sure you read the manual as the GNU and BSD versions differ on how they deal with the arguments.

BSD version:

```
dos2unix $FILENAME $FILENAME_OUT
mv $FILENAME_OUT $FILENAME
```

GNU version:

```
dos2unix $FILENAME
```

Alternatively, you can create your own `dos2unix` with any of the proposed answers here, for example:

```
function dos2unix(){
    [ "${!}" ] && [ -f "{$1}" ] || return 1;

    { echo ':set ff=unix';
      echo ':wq';
    } | vim "${1}";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you create a file in Notepad or [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) in Windows, bring it to Linux, and open it by Vim, you will see ^M at the end of each line. To remove this,

At your Linux terminal, type

```
dos2unix filename.ext
```

This will do the required magic.

Comment: [dos2unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) is not installed by default on e.g. [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

Comment: Much older answers already cover this solution in detail.