# VIM Ctrl-V Conflict with Windows Paste

Tags: windows, vim

I am using VIM in Windows. The problem is that I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> as a visual mode. However, this key has conflict with Windows paste. How can I reset this key back to VIM visual mode instead of pasting. I prefer to set this in my _vimrc configuration file.

Comment: If you are using Vim inside the *"Windows Terminal"* ([link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701#activetab=pivot:overviewtab)) it is really easy to just open *"Windows Terminal's Settings"*, navigate to the *"Actions"*, delete key bindings for CTRL+V and CTRL+C and voila! You have a much more Linux-friendly environment and Vim will also work!

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment. It's a very nice solution.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

From [the VIM documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_w32.html#CTRL-V-alternative):

> Since <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> is used to paste, you can't use it to start a blockwise Visual
>   selection.  You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> instead.  You can also use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> in Insert
>   mode and Command-line mode to get the old meaning of <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.  But <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>
>   doesn't work for terminals when it's used for control flow.

Comment: I like this better than fiddling with _vimrc. It works immediately and since I am unlikely to be on serial terminals in the future, the Ctrl-S/Ctrl-Q flow control is a non-issue.

Comment: On Linux (Gnome terminal) I found it better to use [CTRL-K C R](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20542768/500942), but I found this answer first.

Comment: For some reason I needed to use the `Shift` key for visual selection on Windows, while I do not on Linux.

Comment: Thanks user132014! I find that you have to use h, j, k and l to navigate in visual block mode using Ctrl-Q, though. This is the case for the gVim editor for Windows. The arrows don't seem to work for me in gVim for Windows when navigating in visual block mode using Ctrl-Q.

Comment: @RatneshChandna - Use `Shift` along with the arrows?  I am seeing the same behavior, but somehow discovered that `Shift` worked.  I didn't know h/j/k/l worked.

Comment: I can confirm this works on mac os and i having the same issue in VsCode and this worked for me.

Comment: Could you please give us the line to add to our .vimrc please?

Answer (score 41):

Check your _vimrc file and see if it sources mswin.vim. That script maps the ^v to the paste. You can either remove that line on your _vimrc file or disable the mapping commands directly on mswin.vim.

Do a :help behave on vim for more info.

Answer (score 25):

Visual mode (and other stuff) working like in Unix requires both JOP's and Windows Programmer's suggestions.

In GVim on Windows, go to the edit menu, click on startup settings, and comment out the windows-specific garbage (using the vimrc comment character, which is a double-quote).  The mswin.vim file is where the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> override is specified, and the behave mswin option makes it so that the arrow keys don't just apply motion like you'd expect (it also changes the mouse selection behavior).

```
"source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
"behave mswin
```

I like to add a black-background colorscheme in there as well, so it looks more like what I'd see in a terminal (and because a light background is great on paper, but awful on a backlit screen):
`colorscheme koehler`

Answer (score 21):

Here's a modern day solution to this problem. It applies to the terminal version of Vim/Neovim, not the GUI version. If you use Microsoft's new-ish [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) (I highly recommend it.), you can redefine its key bindings to your advantage. The following section of the settings file is initially **NOT** commented out. If you comment it out, as I've shown, `Ctrl+V` becomes the rectangular visual select key in Vim we all know and love.

```
// Copy and paste are bound to Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+Shift+V in your defaults.json.
// These two lines additionally bind them to Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V.
// To learn more about selection, visit https://aka.ms/terminal-selection
//{
//    "command": {
//        "action": "copy",
//        "singleLine": false
//    },
//    "keys": "ctrl+c"
//},
//{
//    "command": "paste",
//    "keys": "ctrl+v"
//}
```

Now here's the weird part. I'd expected this to change the behavior of `Ctrl+V` outside of Vim in the Terminal, so I checked. It still does a paste, but it's different than the Ctrl+Shift+V paste. Inside Vim, however, all is good: `Ctrl+V` for rectangular select; and `"*P`, `Ctrl+Shift+V`, or `Right Mouse Button` for pasting from the clipboard.

Comment: This really messed with me. What kind of ridiculous defaults are those...

Comment: Thanks: exactly the information I needed! I wish I could give you more kudos.

Comment: You can also open the Settings Tab (CTRL+,), go to Actions and delete the CTRL+V Paste entry

Answer (score 20):

If this line in your _vimrc troubles you:

```
behave mswin
```

then delete that line.

Answer (score 14):

I prefer the same keystrokes everywhere so I use this in my .vimrc to override mswin.vim:

```
if has('win32')
  " Avoid mswin.vim making Ctrl-v act as paste
  noremap <C-V> <C-V>
endif
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure there is a lot you can do about that.  You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> instead though.

Answer (score 8):

For the Windows Terminal (PowerShell), click on the Dropdown arrow right next to the Shell-Tab and select settings. In the `"actions"` section of `settings.json` you can comment out the following lines so they're saying:

`// { "command": {"action": "copy", "singleLine": false }, "keys": "ctrl+c" },`

and

`// { "command": "paste", "keys": "ctrl+v" },`

This unbounds `Ctrl+V` and `Ctrl+C` from Paste and Copy. However due to the `defaults.json` you're still able to use `Shift+Ctrl+C` and `Shift+Ctrl+V` for Copy and Paste with this solution.

Please see Phil R comment. Didnt see his solution in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

The combination of jop's advice (looking for mswin.vim in the default _vimrc file) and "Windows programmer's" advice (getting rid of the "behave mswin" line) worked like a charm for me.

(my rep is too low to vote them up or combine them -- someone clean this up for me, or I'll come back once my rep is higher)

Comment: In other words, were you trying to leave a comment?

Comment: Heh, I'm an infrequent stackoverflow user (hence my low reputation)

Answer (score 3):

In Windows Terminal, the `CTRL+V` shortcut is assigned to *paste* command by default. If you use Vim in Terminal, you can **change the *paste* key binding in Terminal**'s *Settings / Actions* menu. (Or use the WSL/PowerShell/Command Promt etc... directly, instead of launching it from Terminal.)

Answer (score 2):

**For VMs on Windows where `CTRL+V` does the pasting:**

Simply do **`CTRL+SHIFT+V`** ... works immediately and similarly to original `CTRL+V` visual selection.
[*<sup>^ Source: Comment mentioned by stevesliva.</sup>*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426896/vim-ctrl-v-conflict-with-windows-paste#comment57203709_426910)

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows-specific mappings as a whole bother you, you can set

```
let g:skip_loading_mswin = 1
```

in your vimrc to disable loading it (mswin.vim) entirely.