# How to input ^M in vim when ctrl-v is used as paste

Tags: vim

My vim used ctrl-v as paste short-cut, which conflict with commands need ctrl-v as shortcut prefix.

For example, `^M` need `ctrl-v ctrl-m`. I can do that in vim command line, and vim without intialization. But the symbol won't go to buffer from vim command line. `:s/aaa/^M/g` doesn't work.

Although, I can use `echo -e "\r"` or no-initialized vim to work around it.

But how to type this symbol in my current vim configuration?

Answer (score 4):

to input `^M` you can try followings:

- `Ctrl-V Enter`
- `Ctrl-V Ctrl-M`
- use digraph `Ctrl-K C R`, `C R` means CR.

Comment: The question is how to insert `^M` when `Ctrl-V` is already mapped - the `ctrl-v ctrl-m` is mentioned by the OP on the second line.

Comment: digraph is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a mapping to the original function of `ctrl-v`:

```
noremap! <C-Q>  <C-V>
```

But as explained on `:h CTRL-V-alternative` and noted by ZyX on the comments, your issues may be that your terminal is capturing the `ctrl-q` [(more details here)](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-32.1). If the mapping above doesn't works you could try mapping to something else:

```
noremap! <leader><C-V>  <C-V>
```

Then hitting `leader` (usually `\`) followed by `ctrl-v` `ctrl-m` should insert `^M` on both `insert` and `command` mode.

Comment: I am in Linux, and the C-V map is configured by .vimrc. noremap doesnt work, which result in a newline, just like before noremap. Actually, c-q works the same as c-v in column-wise mode before noremap, so I guess noremap is not necessary.

Comment: @MartinWang I'm not sure if I understood your comment. You said that C-V is map is configured on .vimrc - if you don't write it yourself, you are probably source `$VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim`, which also creates the C-Q mapping. Is this second mapping, which is copied on my answer, that you mean that doesn't work? If that is the case, what exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you aware that Vim has multiple editing modes? Because you are comparing C-Q with C-V in `normal` mode, but your is about `command` line mode - if you type C-Q followed by enter you should get the ^M on you substitute cmd

Comment: I map it by myself rather than mswinvim. Command line mode is fine. Insert mode doesnt work, `C-Q C-M` results in a newline. I mean C-Q is an alternative of C-V by default, and it is the case in normal mode. In command, `C-Q Enter` also results in a 'newline' to execute the command, resulting an error.

Comment: @MartinWang `C-q` in terminal vim is captured by the terminal (`<C-s>`/`<C-q>` pair: first to freeze scrolling (and sometimes freeze the running application), second to unfreeze it). You need to disable this functionality (usually done by `stty -ixon`, but terminal emulator may refuse to use stty settings (AFAIR konsole does) in which case you should check out its documentation) (if this does not work and you are using zsh make sure you either do not have `ttyctl -f` run somewhere or you run `stty -ixon` before `ttyctl -f` (you may use just `ttyctl` to check whether tty settings are frozen)).

Comment: @MartinWang Or you can simply choose some key that is not `<C-q>`.

Comment: And @mMontu you are wrong with the command you use: if OP wants to input raw control character he is very much likely wants this in *insert* or *command* modes. None of these modes are covered by `noremap` command. There is `noremap!` (note the bang) to cover insert and command at once and `inoremap`/`cnoremap` to cover them on individual basis. In any case there is no way mapping `noremap <C-q> <C-v>` will serve this purpose: you need something like `noremap <C-\><C-n>i<C-v>` to enter raw control character from modes covered by `noremap`.

Comment: @MartinWang As you already see `<C-q>` as a default alternative to `<C-v>` I guess you are not affected by terminal issues. That means all you need is taking the above mapping and adding a bang after the command.

Comment: @ZyX indeed, I believed that map covered the insert and command modes. I've updated the answer according to your comments.

Answer (score 1):

try `Ctrl-Q Enter`

(This solution also works when you try to enter digraphs by number in Vim)