# R comment character, #, does not work

Tags: r, vim

I have a text file containing the following 5 lines of code:

```
#
# 1991    60060GBNYPAN
# 1991    60061GBGTSJT
# 1991    60062GBGTSJT
#
```

If I open the default `R GUI` on a Windows machine and paste in those five lines I obtain the following:

```
> #
> # 
> 1991    60060GBNYPAN
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "1991    60060"
> # 1991    60061GBGTSJT
> # 1991    60062GBGTSJT
> #
>
```

When I paste the same five lines of code instead into the `Stack Overflow` question window I obtain:

```
#
# 
1991    60060GBNYPAN
# 1991    60061GBGTSJT
# 1991    60062GBGTSJT
#
```

If I open the text file containing that code into `gVim 7.4` I see:

```
#^M
# 
1991    60060GBNYPAN^M
# 1991    60061GBGTSJT^M
# 1991    60062GBGTSJT^M
#^M
```

All characters are blue in `gVim 7.4` except that in the third row the (first) `1991` is in pink font and `60060GBNYPAN` is in black font.

I can remove the `^M` by typing:

```
:%s/<ctrl>Q<ctrl>M//g<return>
```

from here: [Read csv file with hidden or invisible character ^M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321175/read-csv-file-with-hidden-or-invisible-character-m)

However, if I then save the file by clicking on: `File - Save` in `gVim 7.4` and then opening the file the contents now look as follows:

```
## 1991    60060GBNYPAN# 1991    60061GBGTSJT# 1991    60062GBGTSJT#
```

If I paste those contents into `R` I get:

```
> #
> # 
> 1991    60060GBNYPAN
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "1991    60060"
> # 1991    60061GBGTSJT
> # 1991    60062GBGTSJT
> #
>
```

the same as before I opened the file in `gVim 7.4`.

If I open the file into `gVim 7.4` a second time (after have removed the `^M` and saved the file) I see:

```
#
# 
1991    60060GBNYPAN
# 1991    60061GBGTSJT
# 1991    60062GBGTSJT
#
```

The color of the fonts has not changed and at the bottom of the `gVim 7.4` window is a message that reads:

```
<comment character does not work2.r" [unix] 6L, 74C        6,1        All
```

The number of spaces before and after the `6,1` is just an estimate.

What is going on?

I guess in addition to the `^M` there is another hidden character in the file that, unlike the `^M`, is not displayed by default when I open the file in `gVim 7.4`.

Thank you for any suggestions.  I might have to load the original file onto `GitHub`.  I will attempt to do that after posting this message here.

**EDIT**

Although I have a `GitHub` account and have uploaded files to it, it has been so long that I cannot remember how to upload this latest file.  Hopefully I will get the file uploaded shortly.

If I type:

`:set list<return>` in `gVim 7.4` after removing the `^M` I see:

```
$
#$
# $
1991    60060GBNYPAN$
# 1991    60061GBGTSJT$
# 1991    60062GBGTSJT$
#$
```

I thought that `:set list` was supposed to reveal all hidden characters, but all it is showing is a blank space between `#` and `$` in the second row (or third row if I count the first `$` as a row).

Comment: There are several types of newline characters, and one of them must be between the "#" and the "1991" on the first "line".

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thank you.  I suspected as much.  Hopefully I can figure out how to see them in gVim 7.4 and remove them.

Comment: Replace them with `ctrl-N` if you want them handled in R. And note that there is a comment.char for read.table that may be needed.

Comment: @BondedDust Thank you.  I tried selected all text in the file and then pressing <ctrl><shift>N but that did not eliminate the error in R.

Answer (score 2):

To find the troublesome character, it's best to view a *hexdump* of the file. On Unix, there are many such tools: `hexdump` / `hd` / `od`, etc.

Since you're on Windows, you can use the `xxd` command-line tool that ships with Vim. `:help 23.4` (Binary files topic of the Vim user manual) tells you how to open the file, and (under *using XXD*) how to view the file as a hex dump.