# VIM: Cleaning up onclick events

Tags: javascript, vim, motion

I am doing some refractoring and one of the objectives is to move some inline js functions in HTML.

```
<a href="#" onClick="function('');">text</a>
```

The idea is to remove the onClick event along with the contents inside the quotes

```
<a href="#">text</a>
```

suggestions to move faster?

I would imagine after doing it one time I can just repeat the motion with . after finding the next instance.

Comment: If you use multiple commands to remove the whole attribute, you can use `q` to record them and then replay them. See `:help record`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple regex should do it:

```
%s /onClick=".\{-}"//g
```

Comment: Wouldn't work for `<a onClick="function('');" href="#">` I guess.

Comment: true, but not sure why? Shouldn't ".*" match only string inside quotes?

Comment: nevermind, I see why. It's because of the ending quote of the last attr.. oops

Comment: A better solution than tacking a semicolon on to the end would be to either use `\{-}` rather than `*` after the `.`, or changing the `.` to `[^"]`.

Comment: It was hard to chose but after trying both solutions this was the best option given an addition to the command %s /onClick=".\{-}"//gc (note the "c") at the end to enable interactivity in order to verify all elements that were to be replaced.

Comment: @HelmutGranda - +1 Choose the solution that works best for you. Considering my own note of warning, interactively changing and being able to verify **is** the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible method

```
%norm / onClick<C-v><ESC>ndt>
```

Breakdown

```
%norm       # following are normal mode commands
/ onClick   # Search for _onClick
<C-v><ESC>  # Exit search mode
n           # goto next match
dt>         # delete till >
```

Note that this can be sufficient for a one time job. If you need a foolproof solution, [this or regex or whatnot is not the right tool for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/52598).

Comment: This worked! The only replacement I had to do was <C-q> instead of <C-v>. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426896/vim-ctrl-v-conflict-with-windows-paste