# gVim showing carriage return (^M) even when file mode is explicitly DOS

Tags: vim, carriage-return, line-endings

I'm using gVim on Windows. My code shows `^M` characters at the end of lines. I used `:set ff=dos` to no avail. The `^M` characters remain for existing lines, but don't show up for newlines I enter.  I've switched modes to mac (shows `^J` characters) and unix (also shows `^M` characters) and back to dos.  Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format for a comprehensive explanation of line endings in vim/gvim. This link also explains how to fix the problem.

Comment: This question is _not_ a duplicate of any of the following three questions, but it deserves to be linked with them, I think.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/5843495
~ * ~
https://stackoverflow.com/q/811193
~ * ~
https://stackoverflow.com/q/82726

Answer (score 144, accepted):

This happens when you have a mixture of Windows line endings and Unix ones. If you have 100 lines, 99 are \r\n and one is \n, you'll see 99 ^M characters. The fix is to find that one line and replace it. Or run dos2unix on the file. You can replace the Windows line endings with:

`:%s/\r\(\n\)/\1/g`

Comment: I usually just whack 'em with `:%s/^M//`

Comment: Should add to `:set ff=dos` if you want it to be dos when you're done, ala Evan's answer.

Comment: Excelent solution! To be more practial in next times add in the .vimrc file:

`command AdjustEndOfLine execute '%s/\r\(\n\)/\1/g'`

So, every time you need to sanitize the file, just use the `AdjustEndOfLine` command.

Comment: See also the section "Converting mixed files" in this comprehensive explanation of vim line endings http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format

Answer (score 45):

You can also run:

```
:e ++ff=dos
```

To remove the `^M`: See [File format – Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format).

Comment: This was what I was looking for, and is the actual correct answer.  Thanks.

Comment: This works well also from the command line: `vim -R -c ":e ++ff=dos" filename`

Answer (score 19):

I usually use the following to cleanup my line endings:

```
:g/^M$/s///
```

To get the ctrl-M I usually type ctrl-Q, then ctrl-M and it puts it in.  (In some environments it may be ctrl-V then ctrl-M.)  I don't know why, but I find that one easier to remember than [rq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799417/gvim-showing-carriage-return-m-even-when-file-mode-is-explicitly-dos/799433#799433)'s.

Don't forget to do `:set ff=dos` as well, or you'll end up saving with UNIX line endings still.

Comment: Yeah, I normally use the ^M version with Ctrl-Q and all that. But it's tougher to explain ;-) and the group match version is copy paste friendly.

Answer (score 15):

I know this has already been answered, but a trick I use is

```
:%s/\r/\r/g
```

This replaces the unix carriage returns with the windows CRLF.  Just added in case anyone else had issues.

Answer (score 6):

You can ignore these chars!

put this into your vimrc

> match Ignore /\r$/

Comment: Good to know this is there, but is there a good use case for leaving mismatched line endings in a file? Seems like it's asking for trouble.

Comment: This is more what I needed (changing the file is not always advisable when it causes massive changes to a file that show up in some revision control systems)

Comment: Unfortunately this changes line endings as soon as you save the file. So it produces exactly these unwanted big changes in whitespace, only without showing you. At least for me. :(

Answer (score 5):

Running Vim 7.3 on Windows 7. I used the following command:

```
:%s/^M/\r/g
```

To create the ^M I typed in CTRL+Q then CTRL+M.

Answer (score 4):

Actually what worked for me (on 64-bit windows, gVIM: 7.2 ) was:

```
:set ffs=dos
```

**not just: ff**

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bit simple for many of you but on the off chance it's useful.

Based on richq's answer, I found these to be useful in my vimrc. Note, the second one is commented out normally because it makes dd a bit confusing since Vim will wait for another key stroke to work out if it's the mapped ex command.

```
function! D2u()
    execute '%s/\r\(\n\)/\1/g'
endfunction
"map d2u :%s/\r\(\n\)/\1/g
```

The first is run by typing `call D2u()` into ex and the second by pressing `D2u` in edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

These are extra CR line endings usually because of a using a file on mixed UNIX/DOS systems.

Possible the shortest answer to remove a single ^M from the end of each line, and what I use, is:

```
:%s/\r
```

which is equivalent to:

```
:%s/\r//
```

but the end slashes aren't required (they're assumed).

Answer (score 2):

tried a lot of things but the following worked

```
:%s/\r/\r/g
```

note: use *g* if you want the effect on the whole file