# ^M at the end of every line in Vim

Tags: vim, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

When I am editing source files using Vim and other editors, sometimes I get these `^M` characters at the end of each line.
I think that it has something to do with editing a file on Windows and then on Linux.
How can I remove all of these automatically?

Comment: It's because Windows uses a two-character sequence (normally written "\r\n") to represent a line break, but UNIX/Linux uses only the second character "\n" to represent a line break. So when you edit a Windows text file on a Linux editor, the editor sees extra characters that it doesn't consider part of the line breaks, so it tries to render them and what comes out is ^M.

Comment: There's a bit more to it than that, David. Vim will happily edit a text file with DOS line endings without showing all those `^M`s. The only indication you have when editing a DOS text file in Vim is if you have `%{&ff}` in your `statusline` option value. Vim shows `^M` when the line ending style is *mixed*. It means you've used a text editor that isn't as savvy as Vim, which hasn't followed the existing line ending style, as Vim will by default. If you use Vim or something else of its calibre on Windows, you won't get wrecked line endings like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert DOS line endings to Linux line endings in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/convert-dos-line-endings-to-linux-line-endings-in-vim)

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[Convert ^M (Windows) line breaks to normal line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/811193)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

As a command, type

```
:%s/^M$//
```

(To get ^M, press ^V ^M, where ^ is CTRL on most keyboards)

Comment: also, :%s/\r$// to avoid the ^V^M hassle

Comment: Or, saving a character: `:%s/\r$`

Comment: @sehe technically saves 2 characters :)

Comment: @glennjackman, your tip was much easier, as I had been struggling to get the ^V + ^M were it was not happening at all. All I was getting was the content in the clipboard (as ^V was effective every time ,despite my repeated attempts with different strategies to get them both).

Answer (score 103):

One easy way to strip out the DOS line endings is to use the `ff` option:

```
:set ff=unix
:wq
```

Now your file is back to the good-old-Unix-way.

If you want to *add* the DOS line-endings (to keep a printer happy, or transfer files with Windows friends who don't have nice tools) you can go the opposite direction easily:

```
:set ff=dos
:wq
```

Comment: vim wasn't finding any ^m, or \r, or any of the other line endings, but this worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Vim would not find any ^M or \r, but this did work for me! Thanks @sarnold

Comment: it would seem git is too dumb to detect this as a single character change. I ran this in Vim and the `git diff` shows every line deleted and every line added :/

Comment: Tommy, that's a limitation on `diff`, not on `git`.

Answer (score 35):

You can do this:

```
:set fileformats=dos
```

It will hide the `^M`'s, without touching the file.

Answer (score 19):

There's a program called [dos2unix](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_dos2uni.htm) that should strip those for you. Windows uses different line-ending characters which is why that happens.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me in a file that had everything on one line:

First find all matches

```
:%s/^M//
```

(To get `^M`, press ^V ^M, where ^ is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on most keyboards)

Then replace with newlines

```
:%s//\r/g
```

Combined command would be:

```
:%s/^M/\r/g
```

Comment: Thanks, wondered how to actually enter Ctrl-M in search-replace!

Answer (score 2):

I tend to run afflicted files through **`fromdos`** before reopening them. `fromdos` is part of the [**tofrodos**](http://www.thefreecountry.com/tofrodos/index.shtml) package.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of the problem may have been through an FTP transfer. When you FTP these files from one box to another, make sure to use ASCII transfers. Use the command "ASC."

Answer (score 0):

```
" put this in your ~/.vimrc file and :source ~/.vimrc
" then you can do: Dos2Unix
" dos2unix ^M
fun! Dos2unixFunction()
    let _s=@/
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    try
        set ff=unix
        w!
        "%s/\%x0d$//e
    catch /E32:/
        echo "Sorry, first save the file."
    endtry
    let @/=_s
    call cursor(l, c)
endfun
com! Dos2Unix keepjumps call Dos2unixFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

mcedit: shift+f2, set unix format (LF), ok

Answer (score 0):

My situation is, I was developing my project on Windows, later I ran a Linux virtual machine, and by sharing folders, I directly opened the project that was originally on Windows in the Linux virtual machine. When I ran `git status`, a large number of files were listed, and each line of these files ended with `^M`. I solved this issue with the following two commands:

`git status -s | grep "^ M" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dos2unix`

`git status -s | grep "^ M" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git add`

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/\r$//
```

Should remove all carriage returns `\r` (displayed as `^M`) at end of lines.