# How to fix windows characters in test files in linux?

Tags: windows, linux, file

I have copied files from Windows.
In Vi I see ^M that don't allow work.
AFAIK this is problem with moving files from Windows to Linux.
Does it possible to fix?
Thanks.

Comment: Already answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110678/m-at-the-end-of-every-line-in-vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using vim (enhanced vi editor) you can do it right in the editor:

1. switch to command mode : PRESS ESC
2. type

> ```
> :%s/\r//g
> ```

and voila :-)

Otherwise if you have the `dos2unx` utility installed then you can use that to remove the `^M` (\r):

```
dos2unx infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Otherwise you can use GNU sed which understands \r substitutions:

```
sed -e 's/\r$//' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```