# Error with vim pathogen inside cygwin

Tags: windows, vim, cygwin, pathogen

I have recently installed cygwin (as I am confined to a Windows OS) and would like to utilize Vim within it.  Everything is installed and I can access vim readily and can modify .vimrc and the like.  From a prior post, I have learned that my plugins must be in vimfiles for a Windows OS and have done so.  However, now when I try to verify pathogen I get an error stating:

```
E492: Not an editor command: ^M (this repeats a couple times)
E15: Invalid expression: exists("g:loaded_pathogen") || &cp^M
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
```

My .virmc (again very basic as just trying to start everything up)

```
version 6.0
if &cp | set nocp | endif
let s:cpo_save=$cpo
enter code here
set cpo&vim
map! <C-Home> <C-Home>
map! <C-End> <C-End>
let &cpo=s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
set autoindent
set ff=unix
set background=dark
set backspace=2
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
set helplang=en
set history=50
set laststatus=2
set ruler
set shelltemp
set viminfo='100,<50,s10,h
set window=55
" vim: set ft=vim :
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Regards,

Comment: it looks like some of your files, `autoload/pathogen.vim` for example, have windows line endings. [Fix that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110678/m-at-the-end-of-every-line-in-vim).

Comment: How do I fix that?  Forgive my ignorance

Comment: I see the link you provided but I am confused to the application of the :%s/^M$// command.  I have tried within vim and opening pathogen.vim and it says the sequence is not found.

Comment: Open `pathogen.vim` in Vim, you should see `^M` at the end of each line. Type this exactly: `:%s/` then hit `Ctrl+v` then hit the `Enter` key (you get a single character that looks like `^M`, it's Vim's representation of a newline) then `//` then the `Enter` key again to run the command. The whole thing looks like `:%s/^M//`. It means "substitute every `^M` in this file with nothing".

Comment: I do that and it responds E486: Pattern not found: ^M

Answer (score 3):

from the shell, try executing the following command:

```
find ~/.vim -type f -exec dos2unix \"{}\" \;
```

this will convert all files under your `~/.vim` directory into unix file format.  it should remove the `^M` errors you're seeing.

Comment: In my environment(Cygwin), this `find ~/.vim -type f -exec dos2unix '{}' \;` works, but yours not.

Answer (score 0):

In your .vimrc file I notice

```
set ff=unix
```

But in vim the following commands explain some things,

```
:help dos-file-formats

If the 'fileformat' option is set to "dos" (which is the default), Vim accepts
a single <NL> or a <CR><NL> pair for end-of-line (<EOL>).  When writing a
file, Vim uses <CR><NL>.  Thus, if you edit a file and write it, Vim replaces
<NL> with <CR><NL>.             

If the 'fileformat' option is set to "unix", Vim uses a single <NL> for <EOL>
and shows <CR> as ^M.

You can use Vim to replace <NL> with <CR><NL> by reading in any mode and
writing in Dos mode (":se ff=dos").
You can use Vim to replace <CR><NL> with <NL> by reading in Dos mode and
writing in Unix mode (":se ff=unix").

Vim sets 'fileformat' automatically when 'fileformats' is not empty (which is
the default), so you don't really have to worry about what you are doing.
```

So, you should try to remove the

```
set ff=unix
```

line, or fix the end of lines of your file.

Comment: Thank you, I added ff=unix after searching some other related postings and forgot to remove it after it failed to help.  This seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Sorry, this actually didn't fix it.  Still get the error for ^M.  Thought it was clean but after reopening vim it still does not work.

Comment: To insert a ^M while in insert mode or while entering a command, you must issue a CTRL+V followed by a CTRL+M. This way you should be able to remove the unwanted characters.

Comment: Are these ^M in the pathogen.vim file?  I downloaded via git within cygwin.  Where exactly do I remove these characters?  thanks

Comment: I guess these characters are there, yes. You'll see them very clearly when editing the file (they appear as ^M ;))

Comment: I have opened pathogen.vim and I cannot find any ^M characters.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.  The above solution (proposed by nullrevolution) of calling "dos2unix" on your bundle files should fix your problem for the current plugins.

For the future, I found my problem was was caused by cloning git repos into the bundles directory with git config core.autocrlf set to true.  After I set the git config core.autocrlf back to false, I git cloned the plugins again, and it was back to UNIX-y file endings.