# Read from a file in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have been trying out different solutions to read from a file in linux with no luck at all. My main purpose is to get a http response from an application and store it in a file.

Here is my Code in a shell script file

```
wget localhost:8080/abc/rest/eventservice/event -O /dev/null -S --quiet 2>&1 | grep "200 OK" > out.txt
while read -r LINE || [[ -n $LINE ]];
do           
    echo "$LINE";
done < out.txt
```

After i executed the above sh file i get the below error

```
'ervercheck.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `
'ervercheck.sh: line 6: `    done < out.txt
```

This line `wget localhost:8080/abc/rest/eventservice/event -O /dev/null -S --quiet 2>&1 | grep "200 OK"` 
prints 
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

I have also noticed that when i try to look through the file content and type `vi out.txt` the content is empty but when i type `vi out.txt^M` then content is there.

Please help me as why the execution of shell file gives such error and why i have the ^M at end of my file name

Comment: You have MSWin line endings in your script. Use `dos2unix` or `fromdos` to remove them.

Comment: which one is MSWin line ending ,this ";"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your script file has windows new lines in it. You can use a shell program `dos2unix` to convert it or search and replace, this answer has more details.

[^M at the end of every line in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110678/m-at-the-end-of-every-line-in-vim)

Update: 
Since you are using notepad++ in windows, you can also choose the end of line character by going `Edit -> EOL Conversion` (see [Choose newline character in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8195839/241294)). After you've done this you shouldn't have to convert the file every time you copy it over.

Comment: Ya, actually i am writing the script in windows and then executing it in linux. i'll try to convert it first

Comment: Excellent! Also, what editor are you using in windows?