# Copy and pasted file names from finder on mac and vim showing ^M after each filename, how to fix?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, vim

I copy and pasted files from finder, into a text file to get the names of the files in a certain directory to a text file. When I open the file the files from each directory are all the same line...
For example: I copy and pasted from the "Hats Directory":
Line1 is:

```
hats1.jpg^Mhats2.jpg^Mhats3.jpg^M...
```

In that same text file I copy and pasted files from the "Shoes" directory
Line 2 is:

```
shoes1.jpg^Mshoes2.jpg^Mshoes3.jpg^M...
```

I have tried

```
:%s/^M//
dos2unix
CTRL-V CTRL-M
```

Neither of them work, am I going about this process the wrong one? Is there a more efficient way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: can you please execute `:.!xxd` on the first line so we can see the hex code of that character`^M` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim: Mac vs. Linux ^M Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633564/vim-mac-vs-linux-m-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more simple way is using `bash` truncate `tr` command.

Just do, `tr -d '\r' < inputFile > outputFile` to remove all the carriage return characters.

Comment: That works to delete the ^M, I can use another command to get each file name on its own line. Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to use another command you can use this command : `:%s/^M/\r/g`

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
:%s/^M//g
```

The `^M` that you are looking for is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: When I use it I get an error saying "E486: Pattern not found :\^M"

Answer (score 1):

These are old style mac line breaks (a single \r).
Try mac2unix

Answer (score 0):

You could get that list *without* involving the Finder and *without* fishy formatting:

```
:r!ls path/to/dir
```

See `:help :r` and `:help :!`.