# getting a "^M" after each line in unix from a java created file

Tags: java, unix, vim

I have a Java program that creates a file and prints a bunch of data using this statement:

```
out.write(data+"|"+data2+"\r\n");
```

When I view this file in vim in Unix I see a ^M after each line.  What is it? What is causing this? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert the ^M linebreak to 'normal' linebreak in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811193/how-to-convert-the-m-linebreak-to-normal-linebreak-in-a-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

^M is character 13 (decimal) which is the carriage return (in your code it's `\r`). Notice that M is the 13th letter of the alphabet.

You can get rid of it by not including `\r` in your code. This will work fine if you're on a unix platform. On windows, the file will look funny unless you're viewing it in something like Wordpad.

Comment: Upvote for mentioning that M is a thirteenth letter of (let me add: LATIN) alphabet.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the platform-specific line separator string instead of `\r\n` when constructing your output string. That can be obtained by `System.getProperty("line.separator");`.

Answer (score 1):

*nix uses \n for newline, Windows uses \r\n and produces that ^M character in vi and the like.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try running the file through `dos2unix` utility in *nix, it will get rid of `^M`

Comment: This works after the file was created. The solution that `Ted Hopp` has given would solve it when you write the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

You'll generally only see those if the first line was a unix line ending (lf) but it also includes DOS line endings. To remove them (and correct the file), load it again using :e ++ff=dos, then :set ff=unix, then write it.

Within the Java code, if you're writing text data instead of binary, use a PrintStream and use print() and println() which adds the correct line ending for your system.