# VI :set list vs. cat -A

Tags: linux, vi, cat

I have two identical files it appears but they are of different sizes. This leads me to the thought that there are special characters within the file i.e ^M

In VI

```
:set list
```

Doesn't show the ^M characters but

```
cat -A
```

does show the characters.

In addition, VI shows the special ^M characters only when they happen at the end of a line.

What gives?

Comment: Sounds like the file has mixed unix `\n` and windows `\r\n` line endings.  Vi/Vim won't display `^M` if the whole file has windows line endings, but will show them if it's mixed.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811193/how-to-convert-the-m-linebreak-to-normal-linebreak-in-a-file-opened-in-vim  I can't remember if calling `dos2unix` on a mixed file will correctly result in a unix-only line ending file but that's worth a try as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about vi, but you see the same thing in Vim:

If every line is `\r\n`-separated, then Vim by default sets `fileformat=dos` and loads the file accordingly. Since the `\r` is part of the line separator, it doesn't show up in the editable text. Vim lets you know this happened by showing `[dos]` in the status bar when the file is loaded.

If you re-read the file as a UNIX file with `:e ++fileformat=unix`, the `\r`s will no longer be considered line separators, and you'll start seeing them in the data instead (with or without `:set list`).

Note: `fileformat` is a Vim feature, and is not available in vi.