# Vim syntax files showing error in GVim

Tags: vim, syntax

I have created a syntax file in VIM windows.It is working smoothly.

Then I used the same file in GVIM also.Then suddenly the GVIM was showing error.

```
line 10:
E492:Invalid expression :version<600^M
```

I am attaching the syntax file I am using here.I tried

`:%s/^V^M//g`

But failed to remove the error...What could be the problem?? how to solve it??

http://wikisend.com/download/717140/verilog_systemverilog.vim

Comment: Try to open in vim, then run this command: `:e ++ff=dos` and save the file - it converts the wrong line endings. If not works, try it out with `++ff=unix`. Use unix format instead of dos for scripts. (sorry, but i don't like to register to 4shared.com to download the file)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert the ^M linebreak to 'normal' linebreak in a file opened in vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811193/how-to-convert-the-m-linebreak-to-normal-linebreak-in-a-file-opened-in-vim)

Comment: not working still that error is present.I have changed the download link..please take a look at it

Comment: @Niloct E486:Pattern not found error comes

Comment: solved...Pasted the file into GVIM.then manually removed all the ^M parts

Comment: @Vineeth: Please self-answer or delete the question then.