# xargs does not read line by line properly

Tags: unix, xargs

Here is my current commands which i use:

```
xargs -n 1 -P 100 php b <links
```

I have a script 'b' and a file with links in 'links' and sometimes I don't know why this doesn't work correctly and add to every line symbol "?"
like this:

```
root     19714  0.0  1.0  19880  5480 pts/2    R+   11:19   0:00 php b http://www.google.com?
root     19715  0.0  0.9  19524  4892 pts/2    R+   11:19   0:00 php b http://www.alexa.com?
root     19716  0.0  1.0  19880  5496 pts/2    R+   11:19   0:00 php b http://www.amazon.com?
```

see to the end of the ps-aux result line is "?" symbol and my file doesn't contain that... but not all the times... what could be the problem?

Comment: Could your `links` file have CRLF (WIndows or DOS style) line endings?  In which case, the `?` represents the CR (carriage return)…  And the fix is to convert the DOS file into a Unix file somewhere along the line: `tr -d '\r' < links | xargs -n 1 -P 100 php b`, for example.

Comment: i build the links file with cat [another file] | sort | uniq > links ; So i don't think is a windows/dos style.... is just weird.

Comment: Does `[another file]` have DOS-format line endings?  If so, `links` will too.  Also, the use of `cat` is often unnecessary, and in this case `uniq` too is not needed; you could use `sort -u [another  file] > links`.

Comment: [another file] is like this: line1\r\n line2\r\n line3\r\n ..etc

Comment: The `\r\n` is one of the ways the CRLF line endings are reported on Unix.  The `\r` notation is used for carriage return, CR, in C and other languages; the `\n` notation is used for newline (NL, aka line feed or LF).

Comment: I will try in 30 minutes how you say, i will come back with an answer

Comment: BTW if i paste the same file with copy paste via vi or nano it works.

Comment: The editors may be converting the file format for you automatically.  See: [How to convert the ^M linebreak to normal linebreak in a file opened in `vim`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811193/how-to-convert-the-m-linebreak-to-normal-linebreak-in-a-file-opened-in-vim/811235#811235).

Comment: i tried with tr -d... it works you can post as an answer and i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer*</sup>

Could your links file have CRLF (Windows or DOS style) line endings? In which case, the `?` represents the CR (carriage return)… And the fix is to convert the DOS file into a Unix file somewhere along the line.  For example:

`tr -d '\r' < links | xargs -n 1 -P 100 php b`

> I build the links file with `cat "[another file]" | sort | uniq > links`. So I don't think it is a Windows/DOS style issue.

Does `[another file]` have DOS-format line endings? If so, `links` will too; the command line will preserve the CRLF line endings if they're in the input.

Also, the use of `cat` is often unnecessary ([UUoC](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) or Useless Use of Cat), and in this case `uniq` too is not needed; you could use

```
sort -u "[another file]" > links
```

> `[another file]` is like this:
>
> ```
> line1\r\nline2\r\nline3\r\n
> ```

The `\r\n` is one of the ways the CRLF line endings are reported on Unix. The `\r` notation is used for carriage return, CR, in C and other languages; the `\n` notation is used for newline (NL, aka line feed or LF).

> BTW: If I paste the same file with copy/paste via `vi` or `nano` it works.

The editors may be converting the file format for you automatically. See: [How to convert the ^M linebreak to normal linebreak in a file opened in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811193/how-to-convert-the-m-linebreak-to-normal-linebreak-in-a-file-opened-in-vim/811235#811235)  Alternatively, if you are copying and pasting, then the copy may well not see, and therefore not copy, the CR characters.

> I tried with `tr -d …` and it works.

Good; that at least means this is a reasonable explanation, and it all makes sense.  If you don't need the list of links separately, you can use:

```
sort -u "[another file]" | tr -d '\r' | xargs -n 1 -P 100 php b
```

This does it all in one command line with no intermediate files to clean up.  You could add `tee links |` before `xargs` if you do want the files list too, of course.

Comment: I forgot to say I filter the file with a php and contains \r\n(windows based) end lines... now i know there was the problem, should be only \n(unix based).