# ^M of CRLF shows up in git, but not vim

Tags: windows, git, vim, carriage-return, core.autocrlf

To my django web project, I'm adding HTML files from a template. In Vim, these HTML files don't show anything wrong, i.e. no CR characters are visible. But when I do a git diff, they show up. Since they're not visible in Vim, I'm not able to do `:%s/^M//g` or `:%s/\r//g`, as both of them show `pattern not found` error. BUT they're still visible in git diff. I don't want them to be seen in git. `git config --global core.autocrlf true` doesn't help either

Comment: vim will auto-detect "dos format" and you won't *see* the carriage-returns, but it will auto-restore them on write.  I have `set ffs=unix " disable "file format = dos" detection` in my `.vimrc` to defeat this by default.  (But that may not be what you want, I'm just showing how to disable auto-dos-mode here.)

Comment: Thanks @torek, I think I got the answer. `:set fileformat=unix` solves the problem, all thanks to your pointers and a little bit of googling :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert ^M (Windows) line breaks to normal line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811193/convert-m-windows-line-breaks-to-normal-line-breaks)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after little bit of googling after seeing @torek's answer.

I just had to do `:set fileformat=unix` in Vim!