# removing ^M from a csv file

Tags: bash

I have a problem when I try to remove ^M from a csv

When I type vim or vi file.csv, I get

```
A, TK,2015-04-06,14.4^M,14.7,10.0,0.0,54.0^M,13.3^M,135.0^M,33.8
B, NV,2015-04-06,14.4^M,14.7,5.4,0.0,47.0^M,14.8^M,97.0^M,31.3
```

I have tried with

```
tr -d '^M' < file.csv > file2.csv
```

But it doesn't remove, also with sed.

Comment: `tr -d '\r' < file.csv > file2.csv`?

Comment: Yes Etan, thanks, now I can remove ^M

Comment: How did you enter ^M ? Did you use char ^ followed by char M (wrong), or did you use CTRL-V CTRL-M (correct) ?

Comment: Here is the answer which you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811193/how-to-convert-the-m-linebreak-to-normal-linebreak-in-a-file-opened-in-vim

Answer (score 13):

You could use `dos2unix` command which is provided to do that.

Using GNU/sed just for fun :

```
sed -i -e "s/\r//g" file
```

Using `tr` :

```
tr -d '\r' <file1 >file2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
perl -pE 's/(\^M|\r)//g' < file >file2
```

should remove

- the *literal* `^M` - sequence of two characters `^` and `M`
- and the `^M` as `\r` character.

Comment: I used `perl -pE 's/(\^M|\r)//g' /var/tmp/screwed_csv_file.csv` and then i have a correct CSV file.

Comment: After doing that, i can use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_columns and `LOAD DATA`. Does it not mean MySQL has BUG? they should document it or should be treated as BUG? it took 4 hours for me to find out.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get that file from? It looks like an old System X file from a Mac. The old pre-OSX OS used `<CR>` as line endings. Unix uses `<LF>`, and Windows/DOS uses `<CRLF>`.

Do you have [dos2unix](http://man.cx/dos2unix). This program can convert line endings from Unix/Linux, DOS/Windows, or System X Macs to any of the formats you want. In your file, I take it you need to convert the `^M` which are ***Control Ms*** and not a ***Caret-M*** to `NL` characters.

Comment: By the way, to do this you need to put `dos2unix` into Mac conversion mode: `dos2unix -c mac <filename>`