# Not expecting correct result using grep command

Tags: bash, shell

Im trying to find a line that contains the word `ell` in a text file, however when I use the grep command my result is `Well I don?t knowthat?er 10, 2016.` I also converted the text file using the `dos2unix name_of_file.txt` command but the issue still lingers. What am I doing wrong? Please let me know.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -f $2 ]
then
    echo The file does not exist
    exit
else
    grep $1 $2
fi
```

Here is my text file:

```
Hello today is September 10, 2016.
NYC.
What the hell is that?
London.
Well I don’t know.
```

The result that I am expecting is:

```
Hello today is September 10, 2016.
What the hell is that?
Well I don’t know.
```

Comment: Can you view the line breaks to see what characters are really in the file? It has to be an issue with the line break characters that's interfering with the way grep is outputting the lines.

Comment: yes, all the lines end with ^M @BrianStephens

Comment: You may want to read this, about converting ^M characters to \r: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811193/how-to-convert-the-m-linebreak-to-normal-linebreak-in-a-file-opened-in-vim

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the format of the text file. I saved the text document using Microsoft Word in a .txt format, however, its default option does not save it to MS-DOS type, either select that type, ASCII, or Western(Text) to resolve this problem.