# View ^M as newline in vim without persistent file conversion

Tags: vim, file-format

When editing a dos-format file from a codebase which is mainly used with Visual Studio in a Windows environment on my local Ubuntu machine with VIM, I get to see the ^M character instead of a newline.

According to the [VIM documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html#digraph-table), this represents the carriage return character.

Further complicating the problem is that this only occurs in certain places in the file, so the newlines don't seem to have a *consistent* format.

By default, VIM recognizes the file as dos file-format, which I see by executing `:set ff?`.

My goal is to edit the file without breaking its platform conformity; I don't want to persistently *convert* the file, only because I'm editing in VIM. Hence, the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5843561/3646263) doesn't satisfy my problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22816221/3646263), doesn't either.

Given this requirement, can I get VIM to just *display* all ^M's as newlines via some syntax highlighting setting?

Note that ^M isn't composed out of plain characters. I you'd insert them manually in VIM, you'd have to insert Cntr-V before inserting each character.

Comment: The second answer `:e ++ff=dos` is actually quite good — `vim` converts the file from dos format on reading and will convert it back to dos on writing. I'm sure this is exactly what you want.

Comment: @phd It doesn't seem to have any effect on the file. That is, when I execute `:e ++ff=dos` while I have the file loaded in a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

> this only occurs in certain places in the file

There's your problem. If CR-LF were used *consistently* for all line endings, Vim would (with `dos` in `'fileformats'`) correctly detect Windows-style line endings, and handle them transparently (i.e. without showing `^M`).

As it is not, Vim detects the file as `unix`, and displays the parts with Windows line endings with a trailing `^M`. You could use the *conceal* feature to hide them:

```
:syntax match hideControlM "\r$" conceal
:set conceallevel=2 concealcursor=nv
```

But if you want to maintain the original structure as much as possible, you need to be able to view them, and add them manually (via `<C-V><C-M>`) if you add lines inside those Windows-style areas.

Many people would argue that such inconsistent line-ending style is a bug and should be converted to an agreed-upon, consistent line-ending style. Most version control systems (I hope you use one) have automatic conversion features that make it easy to achieve interoperability with both Windows and Unix users.

Comment: How could I possibly not use version control? :) I didn't know that most have automatic conversion features though. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'm probably going to settle on fixing the line inconsistencies by replacing the `^M` characters with newlines.

Comment: *You could use the conceal feature to hide them:*. *Just* concealing them doesn't solve the problem; they are supposed to be interpreted as legitimate newlines. If not, that a distorted view results in some places.

Comment: If you replace `^M` with a newline, don't you have two subsequent ones (with a Unix view of newline = LF)?! For Windows, `^M` alone isn't a newline, it's the CR-LF combination: `^M^J`.