# Why is cat printing only the first and last line of file?

Tags: bash, macos, cat

I have a txt file with an `#header`. If I use `cat` the output is only the first and the last lines despite the file being a few hundred lines long. What is going on?

**EDIT**

A minimal example is pretty much what you imagine:

`file.txt` is

```
#header 2.0
2.0
2.1
2.2
...
...
...
18.2
```

and the result of `cat file.txt`is

```
[Desktop]$ cat file.txt 
#header 2.0
18.2[Desktop]$
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? No one knows why without being able to reproduce.

Comment: Without showing your samples of input and error it is quite difficult to even understand problem, Please post samples in code tags(not in images) and let us know then.

Comment: well, I still can't reproduce the behavior. Can you show us what `type cat` says? Does `cat` behave normally on another file?

Comment: `[Desktop]$ type cat` produces:
`cat is hashed (/bin/cat)`
On other files it behaves normally

Comment: Maybe some issue with line breaks, is the file originally from a Mac? What does it look like in Text or some other text editor?

Comment: @Manfredo, could you please check once `cat -v Input_file` and let us know if it has some mysterious characters in it?

Comment: Yes that was also my guess but it looks normal. It's a file I copied from excel but in textedit it looks normal. `file -i` says `regular file`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 There are a lot of `^M1 ^M2 M^3` ecc. characters... How to I correct for that?

Comment: @Manfredo, aah ha, try to remove them by using `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` and then do `cat Input_file` and  let us know then?

Comment: `tr` did not do the trick for me. I found the best solution to be editing the file in vim as it is described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811193/how-to-convert-the-m-linebreak-to-normal-linebreak-in-a-file-opened-in-vim    (:%s/<Ctrl-V><Ctrl-M>/\r/g)

Comment: Even better with the utility `dos2unix`, only caveat is that for mac that needs to be `mac2unix file.txt`