# Notation of vim haskell and functions to implement SKI in Haskell

Tags: haskell, vim

Trying to implement SKI combinators in Haskell... Im not sure what `^M` represents but i think it has something to do with the notation of vim while editing a haskell file. Also what is the type notation of the function `eliminate`? Thanks

```
data Exp = Var String | App Exp Exp | Lam String Exp | S | K |I ^M
transform (Lam x y) = (eliminate x y)


eliminate x S = App K S^M
eliminate x K = App K K^M
eliminate x I = App K I^M
eliminate x (Var y)
                | x==y      = I
                | otherwise = (App K (Var y))

eliminate x (Lam y z) = eliminate x (eliminate y z)^M

eliminate x (App y z) = (App (App S (eliminate x y)) (eliminate x z))^M
```

Comment: Doesn't `^M` stand for "Control-M", which means usually "Enter" or "New line" in most shells and some editors?

Comment: Perhaps your file has some inconsistent newline separators: some lines end with CRLF (windows style) while others end with LF only (mac/unix style). Vim opens the file in unix mode, but notices additional CRs around. I'd remove those ^Ms.

Answer (score 2):

You have ^M linebreaks. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811193/how-to-convert-the-m-linebreak-to-normal-linebreak-in-a-file-opened-in-vim) says you can fix it by doing `:e ++ff=dos` in vim. But I can't ensure you that, since I use emacs.

What do you mean when you say *type notation*? If you mean the *type signature*, it is

```
eliminate :: String -> Exp -> Exp
```

Comment: Mateen Ulhaq's comment there indicates that you need to use "`:e ++ff=dos` followed by `:set ff=unix` [to] convert the endings to a sane format." The OP there indicated that that was correct.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in some comments some of the lines contain the DOS end-ofline `CRLF`, some are Unix end-of-line `LF`. To fix it to Unix only:

```
:%s/\r$//
```

I can't say anything about Haskell.