# What is ^M and how is it generated?

Tags: vim, line-endings

Recently, someone (who is using Windows10) ask me that his VSCode's remote (ssh) connect is unavailable. After a bunch of checking, I found his `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` ends with **"^M"** (in Vim) and removing that symbol resolves his problem.

To modify/remove "^M" is easy. But this time I'd like to figure out what is "^M" and how it is generated? Knowing how it is generated would help people avoid generating "^M" and related issues.

Comment: Don't know why this question got downvoted...If you think it's a bad question, please comment out why you think it is bad and even please give advice about how to improve it....instead of just downvote it.

Comment: Hi,  if you look at @m000 's answer to this question, https://superuser.com/questions/473614/vim-shows-m-symbols-and-they-arent-disappearing, you will see a good explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert the ^M linebreak to 'normal' linebreak in a file opened in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811193/how-to-convert-the-m-linebreak-to-normal-linebreak-in-a-file-opened-in-vim)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+%22%5EM%22

Comment: @PatrickBacon  @phd  My question concern what does `^M` mean and how it is generated, instead of how to modify/remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^M` is Vim's representation of ASCII 13 (M being the 13th letter of the alphabet), carriage return. `ssh` assumes that the file will use Unix line endings, so it treats the CR of the CR/LF pair in the DOS file as a regular character, rather than ignoring it as a line terminator. Removing the ^M essentially converts the file from a DOS text file to the POSIX text file that `ssh` expects.

Comment: typo: CF/LF => CR/LF