# gVim - Pattern not found: ^M when trying to remove newline

Tags: vim, newline

I am working with gVim in Windows, and when I open files edited by others I see ^M instead of newlines. I have tried using `%s/^M/\n/g` to replace all instances of ^M with a newline, but I keep getting the error: Pattern not found: ^M. I have also tried `%s/^M/\r/g`, but I receive the same error.

There are still several instances of ^M in the file, why can't Vim identify them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> before pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> in your substitute command.

This allows you to escape the next control sequence properly.

Here are a couple links I found by googling: `vim remove control m`:

- http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/150/remove-m-characters-at-end-of-lines-in-vi/
- http://dailyvim.blogspot.com/2009/01/removing-ctrl-m.html
- [gVim showing carriage return (^M) even when file mode is explicitly DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799417/gvim-showing-carriage-return-m-even-when-file-mode-is-explicitly-dos)

Comment: If you're using Cygwin, you can use the `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` command to convert newline chars.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's carat-M and not ctrl-M? If it's carat-M (^M) then it will be two characters. If it's ctrl-M it will be one. If it's the latter, then [here's your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136915/1127433).