# How to change file format from Windows to Unix

Tags: eclipse, unix, editor

I am using the Eclipse code editor to work on my remote files.
It appears that Eclipse is set to dos/Windows file format.
I do not know how to find the file format set in Eclipse, but
I want it to be set to Unix file format.

How can I set the file format to Unix in Eclipse?

[Similar Question to set file format in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/how-do-i-convert-dos-files-to-linux-files-in-vim)

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: It worked fine. Now my editor is set to Unix file format.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I don't have Eclipse installed to check, but from some searching it looks like there are two things to do.

To change the default format for new files:

`Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> New text file line delimiter`

To convert the file that's open:

`File -> Convert Line Delimiters To -> Unix`

Comment: I do not have option for New test file line delimiter for workspace option

Comment: What version of eclipse? The documentation shows that option: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-9.htm

Answer (score 18):

Take look of following image for changing format:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> New text file line delimiter
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This can even be done more specific, just for a single project:

> **Change Project > Properties > Resource : New Tex File Delimiter**