# Eclipse is auto-converting line delimiters

Tags: php, eclipse, unix, delimiter

Eclipse is auto-converting UNIX new line delimiter (LF) to Windows (CRLF). If I open a PHP file created with UNIX new line delimiter and I edit it in some cases the new delimiters are converted to Windows format. How can I avoid this?

I use "Eclipse for PHP Developers"
Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415
Windows 7, 64 bits

I have the same version of Eclipse installed on another computer but there I don't have this problem. On the other computer windows is on 32 bits.

Comment: This has already been asked and [answered here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374728/eclipse-editor-how-to-change-file-format-from-dos-to-unix

Comment: I don't want to convert the files, I want to avoid to auto-converting.

Comment: The first part applies. If you set your preferred new line delimiter to UNIX then the conversion will not occur anymore.

Comment: There are also some files on project encoded on Windows, which I don't want to be converted to Unix (I know that all the files should be on the same format, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to change the old files). If the files are using different delimiters compare feature is not working properly.