# ubuntu /usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu-9.04

I update the kernel, after that the Ubuntu doesn't work well, PS: I try to exec "meld" command, it will report that "/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory", 
then I exec "sudo apt-get install python" and get the result "python is already the newest version.", what should I do for it.

---

I'm not good at linux, can you tell me how to revert my linux to the last right status, or reinstall the python normally.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Access python from /usr/bin/env?

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong PATH set in the environment at that point.  Use ubuntu.stackexchange.com for ubuntu-specific questions!

Comment: or go here http://ubuntuforums.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109771/python-101-cant-open-file-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 344):

**Problem scenario**:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

**Possible Solution #1**

- If Python 3 is not installed, install it: `apt-get install python3`

**Possible Solution #2**

- If Python 3 has been installed, run these commands: `whereis python3`
- Then we create a symlink to it: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

**EDIT:** hi everyone, I noticed that @mchid posted a better [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65059966/) below my answer: `sudo apt install python-is-python3`.

Comment: Worked for me as well with Ubuntu 20.04 except that I put the symbolic link into my `/home/user/bin` folder instead as I did not want to clutter up `/usr/bin`.

Comment: This obviously fixes this problem, but I'm a little shocked it's the "correct" fix for this. Why isn't the regular python3 on the system path being used? Is this the fault of the developer of the script/application? An old Python 2 standard that fell out of use? Is there some other reason this doesn't "just work"?

Comment: @Manius, once I tried to remove Python2, I broke my distro so badly that even my Ethernet card wasn't working. I had to manually port Python2 back to my distro with a USB sick and compile it from there. There are tons of legacy code that still need Python2 and believe me, we will not remove Python2 for a long time. For the same reason Windows still has to support all the old C++ libraries and version. It's called Backward compatibility and that's the price to pay. By default the distro needs Python2.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani, because half your system is build with python. I remeber when I, as a beginner, run sudo apt uninstall python, and it uninstalled the whole gome desktop with it. I was left with a shell.  I also think this isnt a clean solution. Some tools may rely in python2, pretending python3 is python2 could cause undefined behavior.

Comment: I faced the sane problem @TheFool but applying the solution I posted hasn't put 131 person into trebles still

Comment: I have used the solution below, it feels more safe if it was shipped in an official apt repo `sudo apt install python-is-python3`.

Comment: @TheFool, I upvoted the solution as it was listed below. Nice catch, much better than my hacky way

Comment: This is great, but how do I undo this?

Comment: This way @Sнаđошƒаӽ: https://linuxhint.com/remove-symbolic-link-linux/ . Does the symlink created you a problem?  Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani thanks, being new to Linux it took me a while to realize that it is just a symlink (a close relative of shortcut in Windows), which I can delete as and when I want. So, no it didn't cause me any problem, but just wanted to undo.

Comment: creating a symlink hleped. I tried alias but it was useless

Answer (score 195):

On Ubuntu 20.04 and newer, there is a package to fix this problem. Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

Run `apt-cache show python-is-python3` for more info.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but assuming this works, it kinda seems like this is the "correct" or best answer here (SO vote count fails again) and that the problem is perhaps a result of a changing standard from python2 to 3. Is that accurate?

Comment: @Manius They answered in May and I didn't answer until almost December. I mean, this pretty much does the same thing (creates a symlink) so "best" is kind of subjective. But yes, this seems to be a result of changing from python2 to python3 — there's actually a package named `python-is-python2` that creates a symlink to python2 for people who need to run old python software.

Comment: I get the timing difference yes. I thought subjectivity wasn't allowed on SO? ;) Just picking on SO's arbitrary rule set. We could make an argument that manually creating a link is a distro-neutral solution, I suppose. Python has a way of agitating me to be extra critical for some reason. Python's environment seems to be a mess whenever I need to deal with it.

Comment: And what does this package?

Comment: @EugenKonkov As stated, you can run `apt-cache show python-is-python3` for an extremely detailed description. I don't think the description provided could be more to the point and concise, while fully conveying exactly what the package is and does. TLDR: it's a convenience package that ships a symlink to point the `/usr/bin/python` interpreter to the current default python3.

Comment: @EugenKonkov If you're not running a Debian/Ubuntu based system and you would like to replicate what this package does, then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61608129/) to manually create a symlink to python3.

Comment: @EugenKonkov Alternatively, you can [edit the shebang on the first line of your python script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66512967/) to point directly to python3. So, instead of `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`, you can edit the python script to use `#!/usr/bin/python3` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` instead. But you would need to do this for every offending script, each time you encounter this error.

Answer (score 72):

Having been momentarily stumped by this error myself, I thought I'd post how I fixed my problem.

My problem was an error:

```
: No such file or directory
```

Which made little sense to me.  My problem is that my editor had silently converted the script from Unix LF to Windows CR/LF line-termination.  A rather unfortunate upshot of this is that "#!/usr/bin/env python" actually became "#!/usr/bin/env python\015" where \015 is the invisible CR character... /usr/bin/env was, then, unable to find a command "python\015" - hence the file-not-found error.

Converting the script to Unix line-ending convention solved my problem... but only after a few minutes' head-scratching.

Comment: thank you very much... and as a side note you can convert win endings into unix endings by `fromdos <filepath>` and `fromdos` utility is in `tofrodos` package in standard repos.

Comment: ubuntu should be smart enough to understand both styles.  what year is this again?

Comment: You can use this in Vim editor to convert file format - :set ff=unix
More details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/82743/9152071

Comment: @endolith it still isn't (well I'm checking on Debian, but I think Ubuntu is the same, the shebang is parsed by Linux the kernel). But the error message is much better now: `/usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 30):

**May 2022**: For anyone who just updated to **Monterey 12.3** it appears the update replaces python with python3. Downloading [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/) fixes the issues in **Xcode** and **git** command line. **Be sure to read the two comments below.**

Comment: For those that aren't aware: Python 2 has been discontinued, it's not even receiving security updates at this stage. It's really quite important to upgrade to Python 3!

Comment: I'm using python via homebrew and got a similar error, so inspired by other answers, I ran `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /opt/homebrew/bin/python` and things magically worked again. Thanks

Answer (score 22):

For people facing the same issue with MacOS and installed python3 with homebrew:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /opt/homebrew/bin/python
```

Comment: it's say file exists

Comment: When I ran `which python3` it came back with `/usr/bin/python3` So this didn't work. My solution came from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591971/how-can-i-fix-the-zsh-command-not-found-python-error-macos-monterey-12-3) Which came from Apple changing the default of `python` to not have v2.7

Answer (score 15):

For those with macOS or M1 machines (tested on 12.5) symlinking /usr/bin/python3 will not work because it's a shim to the xcode python3 installation. Symlinking against the shim will just result in an endless cycle of being prompted by the xcode installation tool to install required binaries.

Instead try:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

to bypass the shim and symlink to the python3 binary (technically this is a symlink to several symlinks to the actual python3 binary installed by xcode but it's sufficient since we really just need to bypass the shim).

As this might change in the future, I'll include these readings on how certain binaries are shimmed in macOS:

https://macops.ca/developer-binaries-on-os-x-xcode-select-and-xcrun/
https://randomtechnicalstuff.blogspot.com/2016/05/os-x-and-xcode-doing-it-apple-way.html

that may be of interest to some.

Answer (score 11):

**Just modify the shebang line**

**from** `#!/usr/bin/env python`
**to** `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, you're good to go.

---

- This is automatically done by
  `sudo apt install python-is-python3`, as @mchid [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65059966/10027592).
- Why this works: If you do `$ python`, it will say `Command 'python' not found ...`, but if you do `$ python3`, it should work.

Comment: This is a better option, assuming you can modify the script easily

Answer (score 5):

creating a symbolic link solved the issue for me

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 4):

**This answer for android build system error**
For Python 3

If you get a "/usr/bin/env 'python' no such file or directory" error message, use one of the following solutions:
If your Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS is a newly installed (vs. upgraded) Linux version:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

f using Git version 2.19 or greater, you can specify --partial-clone when performing repo init. This makes use of Git's partial clone capability to only download Git objects when needed, instead of downloading everything. Because using partial clones means that many operations must communicate with the server, use the following if you're a developer and you're using a network with low latency:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master --partial-clone --clone-filter=blob:limit=10M
```

you can see document in
[Downloading the Source](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading)

Comment: getting error ` Operation not permitted`, do i need to create dir called `python` first

Answer (score 3):

Additional possible solution if the other suggestions from the mates are not working is to convert the `.py` scripts into UNIX format.

You can do so by installing dos2unix, before converting your scripts. You can do with something like this:

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

Once installed, you can convert your script accordingly:

```
dos2unix <filename>.py
```

You can read more here about [dos2unix](https://dos2unix.sourceforge.io/).

--

Separately, do try to run your script locally and see if it's working, you will also need to take note to include the [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

- Note that above is for `python3`, use `python` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check if python appears with this command:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep python
```

or

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
```

```
ls /usr/local/bin/python*
```

These commands should check if it is installed and provide you with the Python paths.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python /usr/bin/python3.x 1 
// Alternative 1
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
// Alternative 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

replace `python3.x` with the version you use.

You can also try this configuration with python2, you just need to modify python3.