# Why do I get an No such file or directory error when executing python script?

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ubuntu /usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655306/ubuntu-usr-bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory)

I'm a new learner of hadoop streaming. And I met a problem learning mapreduce.
Here is my code for `mapper.py`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import sys

# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()
    # split the line into words
    words = line.split()
    # increase counters
    for word in words:
        # write the results to STDOUT (standard output);
        # what we output here will be the input for the
        # Reduce step, i.e. the input for reducer.py
        #
        # tab-delimited; the trivial word count is 1
        print '%s\t%s' % (word, 1)
```

When I execute the following :

```
hadoop@Chris-ubuntu:/home/test$ echo "I love China I love ieee I love python" | /home/test/mapper.py
```

I got the result:

```
: No such file or directory
```

However, I'm sure that the file really exists in that path, which can be seen by `ls`. So I just wonder how can I solve the problem.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655306/ubuntu-usr-bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Python files aren't executable by default, so you will have to tell the python interpreter to run your file:

`echo "I love China I love ieee I love python" | python2 /home/test/mapper.py`

or, you can make your file executable by typing:
`chmod +x mapper.py`
and then run

`echo "I love China I love ieee I love python" | /home/test/mapper.py`