# How do I run my Python script? Why does the command line tell me "no such file or directory"?

Tags: python, cmd, working-directory

I have Python 2.7 installed at `C:\Python27` and I have added the path `C:\Python27\;` to the environment variables and `.py:` to PATHEXT. I am able to launch Python.

I downloaded a folder `google-python-exercises` to my desktop, which contains a script `hello.py`.

Following the advice [in the Google Developers course](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/set-up), I try to run the script by using `python hello.py` at the command prompt.

When I attempt this, I get the message: `python: can't open file 'hello.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. What is wrong, and how am I supposed to fix it? I found that I can solve the problem by  running cmd from the folder, but this seems like a temporary solution.

Comment: Is your working directory the same directory that the `.py` file is in?

Comment: Using "cmd", move yourself (using cd <path> command) to the hello.py containing folder, then run: python hello.py

Comment: go to the file directory where hello.py via cmd and then execute python hello.py.

Comment: Yes, are you trying to execute the cmd in same directory where `hello.py` is ? Also check if there are read and execute permissions.

Comment: Press shift+right click on the folder you've downloaded hello.py and open a cmd there. `python hello.py` should work

Comment: Thank you. How do I add a directory in Python?

Answer (score 16):

Python cannot access the files in the subdirectory unless a path to it provided. You can access files in any directory by providing the path. `python C:\Python27\Projects\hello.py`

Comment: Thanks. Moving the file works, but if I move the entire folder then it doesn't. How can I change the directory to include the entire folder and subfolders?

Comment: When running Python from the command line, it will only search for `hello.py` in the list of files in the directory. If your file is in a subdirectory you will have to `cd` to that subdirectory, or add the path to the file. Example: `python C:\Python27\Projects\hello.py`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by navigating to C:\Python27\Scripts folder and then run file.py file instead of C:\Python27 folder

Answer (score 0):

Options include:

- Run the command from the folder where `hello.py` is located (this way, `hello.py` is already a relative path to the file). This is the solution that OP found.
- Give a proper path to the `hello.py` file - either absolute (e.g. `C:/Users/me/Desktop/google-python-exercises/hello.py`) or relative (for example, `google-python-exercises/hello.py`, if the current working directory is the desktop).
- Add a path to the folder (`C:/Users/me/Desktop/google-python-exercises`) to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, and run the code as a module (`python -m hello`).

In all cases, a path is being given directly - Python will not "search" for the file.

Answer (score -1):

From your question, you are running python2.7 and Cygwin.

Python should be installed for windows, which from your question it seems it is. If "which python" prints out /usr/bin/python , then from the bash prompt you are running the cygwin version.

Set the Python Environmental variables appropriately
, for instance in my case:

```
PY_HOME=C:\opt\Python27
PYTHONPATH=C:\opt\Python27;c:\opt\Python27\Lib
```

In that case run cygwin setup and uninstall everything python.
After that run "which pydoc", if it shows

```
/usr/bin/pydoc
```

Replace /usr/bin/pydoc
with

```
#! /bin/bash
 /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/cmd /c %PYTHONHOME%\Scripts\\pydoc.bat
```

Then add this to **$PY_HOME/Scripts/pydoc.bat**

```
rem wrapper for pydoc on Win32
@python c:\opt\Python27\Lib\pydoc.py %*
```

Now when you type in the cygwin bash prompt you should see:

```
$ pydoc
 pydoc - the Python documentation tool

 pydoc.py <name> ...
   Show text documentation on something.  <name> 
   may be the name of a Python keyword, topic,
   function, module, or package, or a dotted
   reference to a class or function within a
   module or module in a package.
...
```

Then change directory to your desktop
$cd /cygdrive/c/users/Szumilo/Desktop/google-python-execises
$python hello.py
Hello World

Comment: The problem is with finding **the script**, not with starting Python. This answer does not address the question.

Answer (score -4):

Try uninstalling Python and then install it again, but this time make sure that the option Add Python to Path is marked as checked during the installation process.

Comment: Why should solve the problem? From the question can be derived that Python is installed successfully and is already in the PATH. It's the Python script that cannot be found, not the Python interpreter.