# Python, unable to open file, Error [2] no such file or directory

Tags: python, shell

I recently started to learn Python using the Google Python Class:

https://developers.google.com/edu/python/

I am using Mac OsX and try to execute a file called hello.py which is part of the tutorial. It is saved in Documents in a folder called Python. 
Sorrily, if I type `python hello.py` in the terminal, I receive this:

> python: can't open file 'hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

I also tried typing: `python ~/Users/sam/Documents/Python/Google` and
`python exercises/google-python-exercises/hello.py`, but I have got the same response.

Has anyone got an idea why this error occurs and can help me to solve the problem?

Comment: This may be because your terminal is operating in a different folder from where you have the Python script. Perhaps you can edit your question to describe where your terminal is pointing (e.g. the output of the 'pwd' command)?

Comment: It's more of a shell than a Python issue I think. You need to either enter the directory where the file is, with `cd`, then run `python hello.py`, or pass the absolute file path to `python`. In your case, the path contains spaces, so you must enclose it within quotes: `python "path/to/the/python/script.py"`

Comment: _"It is saved in Documents in a folder called Python"_ Then why did you attempt to execute it in your home directory, then in _"~/Users/sam/Documents/Python/Google python exercises/google-python-exercises/"_? Execute it from the place where you put it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 101: Can't open file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109771/python-101-cant-open-file-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your files, left click on the folder that the file is saved in. Select open in terminal, and in terminal type 'python hello.py'. This works for linux, and may work for mac because of the unix terminal.

Comment: I suspect you mean 'right-click' not left; as left simply selects and right typically opens a context menu.  That said, many macs don't have right-click and may need to command-click or similar.  In all I'd recommend looking up the correct behaviour on the user's OS before giving actual instructions.