# How can I fix the "zsh: command not found: python" error? (macOS Monterey 12.3, Python&nbsp;3.10, Atom IDE, and atom-python-run 0.9.7)

Tags: python, macos, terminal, atom-editor, macos-monterey

Since I got the [macOS v12.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey) update (not sure it's related though), I have been getting this error when I try to run my Python code in the terminal:

[image: Python not found error]

I am using Python 3.10.3, [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)) IDE, and run the code in the terminal via atom-python-run package (which used to work perfectly fine). The settings for the package go like this:

[image: atom-python-run-settings]

The `which` command in the terminal returns the following (which is odd, because earlier it would return something to just `which python`):

[image: Which Python]

I gather the error occurs because the terminal calls for `python` instead of `python3`, but I am super new to any coding and have no idea why it started now and how to fix it. Nothing of these has worked for me:

- I deleted and then reinstalled the Python interpreter from python.org.
- I tried `alias python='python3'` (which I saw in one of the threads here).
- I tried `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"` (which I found [here](https://osxdaily.com/2018/05/24/command-not-found-mac-terminal-error-fix/)).
- To reset zsh and paths, I deleted all associated hidden files in `/local/users/` and ran the terminal once again.
- I deleted everything and reinstalled Mac OS X and the Python interpreter only to get the same error.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71591971/edit) (it covers terminal output as well).

Answer (score 142, accepted):

OK, after a couple of days trying, this is what has worked for me:

1. I reinstalled Monterey (not sure it was essential, but I just figured I had messed with terminal and `$PATH` too much).
2. I installed `python` via `brew` rather than from the official website.
   It would still return `command not found` error.
3. I ran `echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc` in terminal to alias `python` with `python3`.

Problem solved.

As far as I get it, there is no more pre-installed python 2.x in macOS as of 12.3 hence the error. I still find it odd though that `atom-python-run` would call for `python` instead of `python3` despite the settings.

Comment: In some cases a program that you are using doesn't look into your `~/.zshrc`. In my case a more portable solution was to run `ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`, which doesn't depend on zsh.

Comment: `echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc` is the right command so it appends a new line before the previous content in the ~/.zshrc file

Comment: You do not need to define an alias if you install Python 3.x using Pyenv, for example. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73772425/505650 for a working solution.

Comment: Works but in my case the path is `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

Comment: If you are on an Apple Silicon , instead, see my answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74356785/12794085 

Brew does not install casks to the directory you are pointing to.

Comment: If you follow this make sure to `source` your `.zshrc` file afterwards.

Answer (score 401):

Anyone updating their macOS to Monterey 12.3 will find that they suddenly no longer have the system-provided Python 2.

The reason for this is that Apple removed the system-provided Python 2 installation ([details](https://macmule.com/2022/01/29/macos-monterey-12-3-will-remove-python-2-7-usr-bin-python/)).

So a workaround/solution for this is to use *pyenv* to install Python 2.7 (or any other specific version you need).

1. Install `pyenv` with `brew` to manage different Python versions: `brew install pyenv`
2. List all installable versions with `pyenv install --list`
3. Install Python 2.7.18 with `pyenv install 2.7.18`
4. List installed versions with `pyenv versions`
5. Set global python version with `pyenv global 2.7.18`
6. Add `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` to `~/.zprofile` (or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc`, whichever you need)
7. Relaunch the shell and check that Python works, or run `$ source ~/.zprofile` (Thanks masoud soroush!)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if the goal is to get Python 2 working on Mac OS Monterey

Comment: Why do all answers lead to `homebrew`? I recently migrated to `pyenv` + `pipenv` for management only using `macports` and I am hitting similar errors. In most cases, the user `$PATH` is screwed-up.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Just same error. Cannot imagine why.

Comment: @surfrider did you add it to the PATH and restart your Terminal?

Comment: Did all step by step.

Comment: But then I just installed python from the official site and it solved all issues.

Comment: This should be the accepted anwser, MacOS Monterey M1 Max

Comment: you can use `$ source ~/.zprofile` for step 7 other than relaunch the shell

Comment: You don't need to install Python 2.x unless you really need to run Python 2 code, which was not the OP's problem. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73772425/505650 for a working solution.

Comment: How do I make `python` an alias for Python 3?

Comment: This worked for me on Monterey 12.6.1. In case it isn't clear, for step 6 enter the following into the terminal: 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"'>>~/.zshrc. 

Note the single-quotation marks; this also didn't work for me until I updated ~/.zshrc.

Comment: for M-chips it will be `alias python="/opt/homebrew/bin/python3"`

Comment: Work perfect for me, I already had python3 installed with homebrew, and now I can use both, python and python3 command.

Comment: Homebrew should not be required to get Python installed.

Answer (score 61):

If you simply installed Python 3, just use `python3` as the command instead of just `python`. In my case, I had to install `pynev` first via [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (executable `brew`) using `brew install pyenv`.

But still after using pynev to install Python 2.7.18 and setting it as a global version using `pyenv global 2.7.18`, I still ran into an error while trying to run `python`.

What worked for me (since I already had Python 3 installed) was by changing my command to use `python3` instead of just `python`. Of course, this won't be a solution to everyone who may want to use Python 2.

Comment: Thanks, adding the ```3``` behind ```Python``` made the commands work! I wonder why this is...anyone an explanation?

Comment: How Can I just us python as a command  that looks much simpler.

Comment: It appears you can use an alias (there are some caveats, though), @SubhanAhmed check out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3

Comment: Your comment addresses only one of the 2 issues.The problem with installing a proper python version and calling it from the terminal has been resolved in one of the earliest answers. What I am left with now is why `atom-python-run` keeps calling for `python` instead of `python3` despite the settings. Please be sure you read the problem and the accepted answer before contributing.

Answer (score 45):

you should try

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

that solve my problem：）

Comment: This also solves my problem.  macOS 12.3, Python 3.11 installed using .pkg from python.org

Comment: In my case help this: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: Also solve my problem in macOS 14.1.1

Comment: Thank you! Finally solved after 3 months

Comment: Trietd this but the syntax error on print command.

Answer (score 26):

I just had this problem on a new Macbook Pro with macOS Monterey, and the below worked for me using Homebrew.

Using `alias` is not necessary when using Pyenv. Tested with Atom 1.60.0 and atom-python-run 0.9.7.

1. Install `pyenv` (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) and its dependencies (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment):

   ```shell
   brew install pyenv
   brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib tcl-tk
   ```
2. Install Python 3.10.6 but I assume other 3.x versions should work as well:

   ```shell
   pyenv install 3.10.6
   ```
3. Add Pyenv to your shell according to the instructions in https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#set-up-your-shell-environment-for-pyenv. In your home directory:

   ```shell
   echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zshrc
   echo 'command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
   echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
   ```
4. Make the installed Python available everywhere (this can be overridden per project or folder, if necessary):

   ```shell
   pyenv global 3.10.6
   ```

Now, the output looks like this:

```
% which python
/Users/jl/.pyenv/shims/python

% python --version
Python 3.10.6
```

If some scripts still fail, check that you have added Pyenv to the necessary shell startup file(s) as mentioned in step 3 above.

Comment: Every time I try to run `pyenv install 3.10.6` I get prompted to install XCode Developer Tools, which is already installed. It says "The 'clang' command requires the command line developer tools." The error in Terminal says: `make: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk '' -find make 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 34304: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)` I'm on Monterey.

Comment: Also failing for me

% pyenv install 3.10.7   
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.10.7.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.7/Python-3.10.7.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.10.7...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.6 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/7s/rdl105q14k5b9d7cqc9l1gsr0000gn/T/python-build.20221010101606.15912
Results logged to /var/folde

Comment: @Corey Even if XCode Developer Tools are already installed, does the error message go away if you run the below command and then try to re-install the Python version?

`xcode-select --install`

Comment: @JaydenLawson Same as my previous comment to Corey: does that work for you?

Comment: You may need to restart your Terminal to see the change.

Answer (score 16):

Try the command `python3 --version` if you have installed Python 3.

Comment: and it was easy like that

Answer (score 12):

Just run the below command in your terminal:

```
echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Basically, here we are saying the terminal to treat python as python3.

Works like magic!

Comment: ...and `source ~/.zshrc` after that, for newbies like me.

Answer (score 10):

Since you installed python3.9> (https://python.org/downloads/) , you just need to run everything with `python3` instead of `python`. You don't have to downgrade your python to use it... It works fine with suffixing python with 3, *i.e.* `python3` eg.
`$ which python3`, `python3 --version`, `$ python3 script.py` etc

Comment: Your comment addresses only one of the 2 issues (and still brings nothing to table as you're not the first one to recommend that in this thread).  The problem with installing a proper python version and calling it from the terminal has been resolved in one of the earliest answers. What I am left with now is why `atom-python-run` keeps calling for `python` instead of `python3` despite the settings. Please be sure you read the problem and the accepted answer before contributing.

Comment: @Kig please be sure to read [ask] and focus your questions on ***one*** specific problem. Questions here shouldn't be asking multiple questions to begin with...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32401300)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with fresh MacOS Ventura with Apple Silicon M1 Pro chip. Seems like brew installs to a different location than before on Apple Silicon?

`/usr/bin/` folder had a Python executable and the version for it was 3.9.6.

So I installed Python using `brew` but then I had to execute it via `python3` command so I ran `echo "alias python=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc` and restarted my terminal. I was prompted with the desired version of Python when executing `python` command.

Comment: Only this worked for me on macOS 13.1 (Apple M1 Max).

Comment: You don't need to restart terminal. Instead run `source ~/.zshrc` to source and update current terminal.

Answer (score 7):

I installed Python then this error occurred and I just run

> echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc

and I t worked.on macOS Monterey 12.4, Python 3.8.9

Comment: this works perfectly fine with my Mac Montery 12.4

Answer (score 4):

I First installed python with brew

```
brew install python
```

Then I tried linking the python with symlinks using:

```
brew link python3
```

And it worked for me.

PS: I was trying to run a shell script and alias approach didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I got `zsh: Command not found python` after installing using `https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.4/python-3.10.4-macos11.pkg`

I solved it by configuring the ENVIRONMENT. I added a line, `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.10`, into the `.zshrc` file (you must be sure it is the true path).

---

My macOS ([Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon)):

`Darwin Johns-MacBook-Pro.local 21.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0: Mon Feb 21 20:35:58 PST 2022; root:xnu-8020.101.4~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64`

Comment: @PeterMortensen I mean that you just add 'alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.10` into the .zshrc file.
That is all.

Answer (score 1):

alias python=/usr/bin/python3

This command works but need to re-enter whenever we restart the termian

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pyenv and on Mac M1, then try switching the python from `system` version to a version that is installed already (ex: `pyenv global 3.8.13`, considering 3.8.13 is another version). In order to check what versions installed use `pyenv versions`.

If you don't have another version, try installing a new one and switch to that new environment (ex: `pyenv install 3.8.13`). Then install using pip. Everything should work fine. thats what worked for me.

and make sure your pip and python are aliased to pip3 and python3 respective in the respective terminal configuration file.

Answer (score -1):

I have a [MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) with an [Apple M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) chip and [macOS v12.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey).

- I deleted all Python versions and cleared the trash
- Opened Terminal and typed "python"
- This prompted an xcode.app update
- Then I downloaded the latest version of Python from python.org (version 2.10.5)
- Installed that version
- Quit Terminal
- Opened Terminal
- Typed "python3"

It seems to now be there OK.

Answer (score -1):

I use brew install `brew install python@3.9`, after installation success I want to know the version of python, I run command `python --version`, and I got the problem `zsh: command not found: python`.

If you install it successfully, please check in the terminal. It will show you if you got problem in install if not problem you just change command from `python --version` to `python3 --version`.

Comment: Your comment addresses only one of the 2 issues (and still brings nothing to table as you're not the first one to recommend that in this thread). The problem with installing a proper python version and calling it from the terminal has been resolved in one of the earliest answers. What I am left with now is why atom-python-run keeps calling for python instead of python3 despite the settings. Please be sure you read the problem and the accepted answer before contributing.

Answer (score -1):

for 3.10.8

install with python with brew command

brew install python@3.10

if you have .zshrc file just edit like this

alias  python='python3'

alias  pip ='pip'

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/libexec/bin:$PATH"

if you dont have .zshrc file:

cd

vi .zshrc

and copy/paste  the line below

alias  python='python3'

alias  pip ='pip'

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/libexec/bin:$PATH"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

*eval "$(pyenv init --path)"*

bash starting will be more slow, just suggest

*export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.pyenv/shims*