# Whenever I try to run a python file in VS Code, it gives me the error: zsh: command not found: python. Anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-line

I am using the application vs code, and whenever I try to run a python file, it gives me the error:

```
zsh: command not found: python
```

I have the python extension and application installed on my computer. I am using a MacBook with the new M1 Chip.

The code is just:

```py
print("Hello World")
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried pasting that exact error in a search engine?

Comment: [how-to-fix-zsh-command-not-found-python-error-macos-monterey-12-3-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591971/how-to-fix-zsh-command-not-found-python-error-macos-monterey-12-3-python)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Because the command character used in MAC is `python3` instead of `python`.

You can `echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc` in terminal to alias "python" with "python3".

You can refer to the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_macos) for more information about the use of vscode on macOS