# Python Command not working in mac terminal

Tags: python, command, line

I keep getting the error "zsh: command not found: python" while attempting to determine what version of Python my device is running.

python -v
which returned - zsh: command not found: python
python --version
returned again, zsh: command not found: python

Please advise

Comment: Doing a small search doesn't hurt anyone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591971/how-can-i-fix-the-zsh-command-not-found-python-error-macos-monterey-12-3

Answer (score 18):

Depending on how you installed Python it will probably be called `python3`, not plain `python`. So `python3 --version` should work. You can then set up an alias for python to point to the correct package. [This](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) article explains a bunch of different approaches.