# Install Salome Failed with error "No module named '_omnipy'"

Tags: python, openfoam

I've trying to install SALOME-9.8 on ubuntu 20.04. After the download and extraction, I ran the script `salome`. But i get the following error:

```
ERROR:salomeContext:Unexpected error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/$USER/Downloads/SALOME-9.8.0-native-UB20.04-SRC/BINARIES-UB20.04/SALOME/bin/salome/salomeContext.py", line 279, in _startSalome
    res = getattr(self, command)(options) # run appropriate method
  File "/home/$USER/Downloads/SALOME-9.8.0-native-UB20.04-SRC/BINARIES-UB20.04/SALOME/bin/salome/salomeContext.py", line 354, in _runAppli
    import setenv
  File "/home/$USER/Downloads/SALOME-9.8.0-native-UB20.04-SRC/BINARIES-UB20.04/KERNEL/bin/salome/setenv.py", line 26, in <module>
    import orbmodule
  File "/home/$USER/Downloads/SALOME-9.8.0-native-UB20.04-SRC/BINARIES-UB20.04/KERNEL/bin/salome/orbmodule.py", line 31, in <module>
    from omniORB import CORBA
  File "/home/$USER/Downloads/SALOME-9.8.0-native-UB20.04-SRC/BINARIES-UB20.04/omniORB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/omniORB/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    import _omnipy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_omnipy'
```

I've also installed anaconda on my pc. I'm not sure if it is related with it.

Comment: Could you please share more details about how you got to this point? Are you in a virtual environment? What commands did you run and in which order?

Comment: I am not working on a virtual machin. I just download the salome from the official website. And I ran the command `${ROOT}/sat config  SALOME-9.8.0-native --check_system`, to check out if i have installed the required package. And I followed the instruction to install the required the package. After all, I ran the script `salome`. I got this error.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. What worked for me:

Deactivate the conda base environment
`conda deactivate`

Create a symlink to phyton
`sudo apt install python-is-python3`

Run salome
`./salome`

More info about symlink [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655306/ubuntu-usr-bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

After that, I've tried to download the image from [here](https://www.code-aster.org/FICHIERS/singularity/salome_meca-lgpl-2021.0.0-2-20211014-scibian-9.sif). But it seems that the container Singularity doesn't work so well on my computer. I can only run the software in CPU mode. And when I was doing something related to the mesh, it would be very slow.

Finally, I installed the salome-meca according to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pufnw9eR-co). After deal with some small problem with the help of the instructions in the video page, the salome works pretty well.