# Mapping leader key to execute something without having to press enter

Tags: vim

I mapped `leader lf` to `LustyFileSystemExplorer` and it works properly. I press `leader lf` and it shows the explorer, however when I change it to any other key binding, pressing `leader lf` shows `:LustyFileSystemExplorer` and I've to press enter to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a carriage return to your mapping:

```
map <Leader>lf :LustyFileSystemExplorer<CR>
```

And you're done!

Comment: hey.... i'm trying to use this to do a simple search and replace like so:

  map <leader>fr :%s/^M/\r/g<CR>

and it doesn't seem to work.... It's supposed to replace dos like line endings with a return.... It works as expected if I type it in, but doesn't seem to if I use it via the Leader mapping I have there.... Any ideas?

Comment: @BradParks: How doesn't it work? You may be better using Vim's native `fileformat` handling: http://stackoverflow.com/a/82803/78845

Comment: @Johnsyweb - great idea on the fileformat, but i tried it and it didn't work... The ^M's still stay the same. And I tried reloading the file again afterwards, and it was still the same. If I manually type ":%s/^M/\r/g" it works, but it only replaces once from the leader key enter substitution. And the "^M" is a special char of sorts... I type it in VIM by pressing CtrlQ+CtrlM on the Mac.... thanks!