# ^M character in VI editor

Tags: special-characters, notepad++, vi, character

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert dos files to linux files in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/how-do-i-convert-dos-files-to-linux-files-in-vim)

I used to edit php programs in notepad++, today when i opened in VI editor.

Every line was appended with ^M character.

What is ^M character? that i don't see in notepad++ but in VI.
Is this new line?

How to disable that in VI?

[image]

Comment: That's usually a sign that the file's been editted on a Windoze box and has been converted to msdos-style line endings.

Comment: @Marc, How to get rid of this?

Comment: There's probably a quicker way to do it, but I'm too lazy to look it up, usually I just got a search/replace: `:g/ctrl-vctrl-m/s///g` (ctrl-v and ctrl-m being actual keystrokes, and not c-t-r-l individual keys.