# How to remove %0D from end of URL when using wget?

Tags: linux, wget

How to remove %0D from end of URL when using wget?

I have a sh script with the following wget. However, when executed on the linux box, wget is attemping the second URL below (%OD attached). How do i prevent this from happening? I have multiple scripts, they're all having the same issue. Thanks!

```
wget https://example.com/info.repo


wget https://example.com/info.repo%0D
```

Answer (score 9):

The `OD` character is a carriage return, part of the CRLF sequence that Windows uses for line endings just to be different as usual.

You can use [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) to fix the line endings before executing, and in future don't use Notepad to write shell scripts.

```
dos2unix myscript.sh
./myscript.sh
```

Comment: No i don't, do i need to install it?

Comment: If you don't already have it then you do.  Which Linux distro is this?

Comment: I'm just kidding, I do have it installed. Used it before as well. But for some reason, it isn't working on this file

Comment: It may be a Mac line break (single 0D). Try mac2unix.

Comment: @ErwinWaterlander OS X just uses `\n`.  The single `\r` linebreaks haven't been used since Mac OS Classic.

Comment: I agree with the answer. However, in some situations dos2unix may not be installed nor wanted. It may be easier to convert the file in VIM as noted in [VIM's documentation](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/File_format). This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/82743/886399) provides more details.

Comment: as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/800644/13983021) to a related question, those without `dos2unix` can use `sed` instead

Answer (score 0):

I had this when running wget from a WSL2 instance based on the [Windows filesystem (`/mnt`) instead of the Linux filesystem (`\\wsl$\`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/setup/environment#file-storage). From WSL2, it in fact is possible to use either.

Running `wget` to download something into a Windows Filesystem directory under WSL2 gave me this trailing `0%D` at the end of the file. I simply started using another working directory under the Linux filesystem, and `wget` didn't give me this problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If dos2unix is not an option (e.g. cygwin) you can open the file in notepad++, Edit->EOL Conversion -> Unix (LF)