# Use wget to download images from a list in CSV

Tags: bash, csv, wget

I have a CSV which has three columns: object-ID, image-url1, image-url2. I'd like to be able to run a bash script that does the following for each row in the CSV:

1. create a new folder using 'object-ID' as the folder name
2. download both images into that folder
3. repeat for each row

I've got this code but it needs some help!

```
IFS=$'\n';
for file in `cat <filename.csv>`; do
echo "Creating folder $object-ID";
mkdir $object-ID
   echo "Downloading image 1";
   wget $image-url1
   echo "Downloading image 2";
   wget $image-url2
done
```

Comment: You need to parse each row and extract the object id and image urls. Awk would be a good start for that. http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/using_awk_on_csv_files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
while IFS=, read objid url1 url2;
do
    echo "Creating folder $objid"
    mkdir -p "$objid"

    # Run in a subshell
    (
        cd "$objid"

        echo "Downloading image 1"
        wget "$url1"

        echo "Downloading image 2"
        wget "$url2";
    )

done < myfile.csv
```

It assumes your CSV uses comma (`,`) as a separator. This can be adjusted by changing the `IFS=,` part in the `while` loop.

Also, if `$objid` contains forward slashes (`/`) in it, `mkdir -p` will treat it as a path with subdirectories and create all of them. If that's undesirable you can replace `/` in `$objid` prior to `mkdir` like so:

```
 objid="${objid//\//_}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great! The only issue i ran into was a %0D control character on the end of the second URL which I resolved with dos2unix via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236197/how-to-remove-0d-from-end-of-url-when-using-wget

Comment: Ran into a small issue - if the objid contains the / character, it starts creating folders within folders. Not sure how to escape the character so that doesn't happen. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks - so that works but objid still stores the old value so it doesn't find the new directory containing _ within the subshell. Not quite sure how to fix. I accepted your answer btw (sorry i'm new).

Comment: No problem, just do `objid="${objid//\//_}"` prior to `mkdir`

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

With `read` :

```
while IFS=',' read id image_one image_two; do
  [ ! -d "${id}" ] && mkdir "${id}"
  for img in ${image_one} ${image_two}; do
    printf "Downloading %s" "${img}"
    wget -P "${id}" "${img}"
    echo "---"
  done
done < file.csv
```

For each line : creates directory based on id value if directory doesn't exist and retrieves images in created dir (with `-P` option of the `wget`).

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F "," '{
     print "mkdir",$1"; echo wget -P",$1,$2"; echo wget -P",$1,$3
}' filename.csv | bash
```