# Function not working in a bash script - error messages relate to '\r'

Tags: bash, function, line-endings

I have recently installed a fresh version of Debian. I created this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

print_something () {
  echo Hello I am a function
}

print_something
print_something
```

However this displays this error upon me issuing `bash test.sh`:

```
test.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
test.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'est.sh: line 4: `print_something () {
```

What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have Windows-style line endings (`\r\n)` in your script, which cause problems; convert them to Unix-style line endings (`\n` only) with a tool such as `dos2unix` or `awk 'sub("\r$", "")+1' win.txt > unix.txt`. Generally, make sure that your editor creates `\n`-only files.

Comment: Where did you write the code? Try running `cat -v test.sh`, and look out for '\r's.

Comment: Thanks  mklement0, that resolved the issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/82743/524743

Comment: @mklement0: please consider writing an answer to help future visitors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Diagnosing:**

- Unix utilities in general expect line endings to be `\n` only, and usually break or show unexpected behavior and output with files that have Windows-style `\r\n` line endings - as `bash` does here.
- Error messages containing the *string* `\r` are an indicator that such Windows-style line endings are present.
- Passing a file to `cat -v` and examining the output for `^M` at the end of output lines (which is how `\r` chars. are represented) is a way to check a file for Windows-style line endings on demand.

**Fixing:**

- To convert a file with Windows-style line endings to Unix-style ones:

  - use the [`dos2unix`](http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/) utility, if already installed (typically, it is *not*), or installing it is an option; how you install it depends on your platform; e.g.:

    - on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install dos2unix`
    - on OSX, with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) installed, `brew install dos2unix`
  - alternatively, use *standard* utilities to perform the conversion; there are several options; e.g.:

    - `sed $'s/\r$//' win.txt > unix.txt`
    - `awk 'sub("\r$", "")+1' win.txt > unix.txt`
    - There are variants of the above commands that update a file *in place*, but they're *platform-specific*, if available at all.
- Make sure that the editor you use to create shell scripts / files for use with Unix utilities is configured to use Unix-style line endings.

Comment: A good answer — the right diagnosis and good support material.  I wonder how many other similar questions have been asked in the past.  I know I've answered similar questions before.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanLeffler. Yes, this problem comes in many guises, and I've answered similar ones before as well. That's what made me post only a comment at first, but since no one has found an obvious duplicate, and also encouraged by Andrea Corbellini, I turned the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by installing `dos2unix` and then converting the file.
Many thanks to mklement0 who pointed this out.

Comment: My pleasure; I've created an answer with more background information.