# How can I execute a command which has a combination of quotes and double quotes?

Tags: bash, quotes, double-quotes, single-quotes, mattermost

The purpose of my script is to send a message to a Mattermost server.
So I use curl to do so :

```
#!/bin/bash
message="This is my message with potentially several quotes in it ..."
url=http://www.myMatterMostServer.com/hooks/myMattermostKey
payload="{ \"text\" : \"$message\" }"
curlCommand="curl --insecure --silent --show-error --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST --data '"$payload"' "$url
echo -e $curlCommand
$curlCommand
```

The echo command shows something which is executable if I copy it and execute it directly in a terminal.

But the last line doesn't execute correctly and I have this in the console :

```
++ curl --insecure --silent --show-error --header ''\''Content-Type:' 'application/json'\''' -X POST --data ''\''{' '"text"' : '"This' is my message with potentially several quotes in it '..."' '}'\''' http://poclo7.sii24.pole-emploi.intra/hooks/iht8rz8uwf81fgoq9ser8tda3y
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'application'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '"text"'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host ':'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '"This'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'is'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'my'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'message'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'with'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'potentially'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'several'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'quotes'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'in'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'it'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '..."'
```

I tried so much combinations of quotes, double quotes and $(command) ... Please help me :-)

Comment: Might be worth putting your whole payload in a file and telling curl to read the file for the data.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007253/send-post-xml-file-using-curl-command-line https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408904/send-post-request-with-data-specified-in-file-via-curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are for data, not code. See [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Define a function instead.

```
curlCommand () {
    message=$1
    url=$2
    payload='{"text": "$message"}'
    curl --insecure --silent --show-error \
         --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
         -X POST --data "$payload" "$url"
}

curlCommand "This is my message with potentially several quotes in it ..." http://www.myMatterMostServer.com/hooks/myMattermostKey
```

Consider using `jq` to generate the payload to ensure that the contents of `$message` are properly escaped.

```
payload=$(jq --arg msg "$message" '{text: $msg}')
```

or pipe the output of `jq` directly to `curl`:

```
jq --arg msg "$message" '{text: $msg}' | curl ... --data @- ...
```

Comment: You can use any language that provides a JSON library; the point is, you should not be trying to generate JSON manually via variable interpolation.

Comment: I finally succeeded in making it work with the 6th method of the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (really good stuff by the way).
I also had a small CR / LF problem that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38912470/2145671) helped me solve.
Thanks again @chepner