# Globally replace all ^M with newlines

Tags: vim, replace, newline, vi

I have a file with `fileformat=dos` where vim shows all newline characters as `^M`. However, when I try to fix this by replacing all occurrences of `^M` with `\r` using

```
:%s/<Ctrl-V><Ctrl-M>/\r/g
```

then the command is not performed globally but stops after the first `^M` character is replaced?

Comment: Try :%s/<Ctrl-M>/<Ctrl-V>, followed by <ENTER>, then /

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. To clarify: in the above command I'm already pressing <ENTER> after I hit <Ctrl-V><Ctrl-M>.

Comment: you could also use the linux `dos2unix` to convert 'dos' files to 'linux' files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert DOS line endings to Linux line endings in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/convert-dos-line-endings-to-linux-line-endings-in-vim)

Comment: Are the `gdefault` or `edcompatible` options off? Read `:help s_flags`.

Comment: @Stas: This question is about a substitution with the `g` flag not performed globally.

Comment: @WillDurst what do you want to achieve? Both `^M` and `\r` represent the same symbol: carriage return.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, after `:set nogdefault` it now substitutes globally.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer thanks to Micheal's comment:

> Are the gdefault or edcompatible options off? Read :help s_flags.

After setting `:set nogdefault` the substitution is now global.