# Why google drive change permission of the file and how to solve it?

Tags: nginx, docker, google-drive-api

I am sharing a project with a non technical team and I share it using google drive. I have a nginx docker that mount the html folder in google drive. But every time I run the docker I always get 403 Access Denied. And google drive also add ^M character at the end of each line of my index.html.

I am using OSX. Is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: 403 indicates that access to the file is forbidden. 
^M has something to do with the file format (dos), which I think docker uses unix for its file formats. More information can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/convert-dos-line-endings-to-linux-line-endings-in-vim). Though this is confusing to me since you're using OSX.
Do the other team members use windows machines? Do they have write privileges on the shared project?

Comment: @adjuremods yes other team members use windows and have write access.
I am wondering why I get 403? Is that because the google drive in windows changes the file permission? And what can I do to prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a docker exec to chmod the files that already mounted does the trick to solve forbidden error. I also learnt that google drive is just not suitable for that purpose and I consider to move to git.