# error while reading a text file from shell script

Tags: unix

I want to read a text file line by line and below is the shell script which I used.I am getting the exception as below :

> fileReader.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
>   'ileReader.sh: line 8:`done < $FILE

### Script used

```
echo "Start"
FILE="/abc/def/ghi/Sample.TXT"
echo "File Path -----"$FILE
while read line;do
    echo "Line # : $line";
done < $FILE
```

Comment: `'ileReader.sh: line 8: \`done ` in an error message sure looks like an embedded CR character. Run `cat -vet fileReader.sh` and see if there are any `^M` characters.

Comment: on running that , I got the below response :

Comment: $ cat -vet fileReader.sh
#!/bin/bash^M$
echo "Start"^M$
file= "/opt/hp/ccdm/var/outbound/Auto_Stand_GS_List.TXT"^M$
echo "File Path -----"$FILE^M$
k=0^M$
while read -r line^M$
do^M$
((k=$k+1))^M$
echo "Line # $k: $line"^M$
done < "$file"^M$
echo "Total number of lines in file: $k"^M$

Comment: OK. This happens with files created on Windows and then copied over to Unix. You can use the [dos2unix](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) program to get rid of those CR characters, or use your favorite Unix text editor. More details in this SO question: [Convert DOS line endings to Linux line endings in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/convert-dos-line-endings-to-linux-line-endings-in-vim)

Comment: I removed it by using your suggestion ,but again I am facing the below problem .                                                                                                            ]$ sh fileReader1.sh
Start This
File Path ----/opt/hp/ccdm/var/outbound/Auto_Stand_GS_List.TXT
: No such file or directoryt/hp/ccdm/var/outbound/Auto_Stand_GS_List.TXT
End this

Comment: That path is not wrong ,if I do a cat operation with that path.I am able to read it ,but this program is not working . Please suggest.

Comment: The overlapping characters in that error message, `or directoryt/hp/ccdm`, may indicate there's still a stray CR there.