# Command not found in bas

Tags: bash, command, cygwin

I'm so sorry because I know this is a dumb question, but I've been trying to figure this out for about 2 hours and I can't figure it out. I've created a `bash` file that uses some other programs (`tcpdump`, `tshark`). The bash runs as it should but on every line that I use `tshark`, `tcpdump`, etc. it says "command not found".

I'm using *Cygwin* on my *Windows 7* VM. All of the files are in the same folder and I I've tried adding the locations of the other programs to the *PATH* variable. I tried commands such as `export PATH=$PATH:filelocation` but when I do `$PATH` those results aren't showing. How can I get these commands to be recognized?

Thank you.

[current errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDdbM.png)

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/convert-dos-line-endings-to-linux-line-endings-in-vim

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't seem to figure out how to use those commands. I'm very new to bash. if my file name is mycode.bash would I just enter :%s/^M//g along with that or somewhere in the code?

Comment: Yes, that should work.  Use `:set list` to see the special characters.

Comment: All of the commands seem to get me the same result. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDdbM.png.

Comment: can you run tshark with full path ? Please note your path has space inside `program files`

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is not a Linux distro, therefore, you don't have all the functionality like you would if you had a Linux installation. 
You could try one of the following.

1) Use Virtualbox to make a VM of some Linux distro and use bash there. You could use Ubuntu server, which has no GUI.

2) Use [this](https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html) site to find packages that will add functionality to Cygwin.

3)Upgrade to Windows 10 and have a native (sort of) bash to use.