# Merge multiple text files with different length

Tags: shell, paste

I have multiple files with simple format like

```
File1   File2   File3
|1|     |2|     |4|
        |3|     |5|
                |6|
```

All files have different length. I try to get the following output:

```
|1,2,4|
|,3,5 |
|,,6  |
```

So each row of the output contains each row of the equivalent input files with a comma as delimiter.

Running the following command

```
paste -d',' input1 input2
```

for two input files gives the suitable output above. However, running the command for three input files results in

```
|1,2|
|,4 |
|,3 |
|,5 |
...
```

Why does the command for two files fail with three or more files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
$ cat file1
|1|
$ cat file2
|2|
|3|
$ cat file3
|4|
|5|
|6|
$ paste -d ',' file[123] | sed -e 's/|//g' -e 's/^/|/g' -e 's/$/|/g'
|1,2,4|
|,3,5|
|,,6|
```

Comment: I have tried this and the problem still remains with my files. Could this occure due to the new line at the end of each line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Post the output of `cat -vet` on each of your files.

Comment: File Nr. 1 gives the output `13$` and all following files have the form `[0-9]^M$` for each line. This differences seem to be weird, as all input files are generated by the same process. How to interpret these outputs?

Comment: The files containing `^M` have DOS-style line endings. You can convert them using `sed`, `tr`, `dos2unix`, and others. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82726/2908724). Fix this issue, then the command above should work as posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I removed the `^M`with the `tr`command and your suggested answer worked fine!