# java.io.IOException: Input/output error at last line of a file

Tags: java

I am facing  issue while processing last line of a file.

> java.io.IOException: Input/output error

```
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)

    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)

    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)

    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)

    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)

    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)

    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)

    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)

    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
```

Everything is working fine, but while reading the last line getting an error at br.readLine().

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file))) ;
String line = null;
 while((line = br.readLine()) != null){}
```

Comment: what is the content of that last line?

Comment: are you using windows or linux?? it could be the line ending format

Comment: @XtremeBaumer some string. consider "jsvdh#1236 25373, 1637 2727, ; 2627, , ,#"

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz linux system

Comment: does it happen with other files too?

Comment: can you write "file xxxxx" (where xxx is yur file name)??

and, can you try it after doing "dos2unix yourfile" ??

Check this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/82743/3617531

Comment: @XtremeBaumer not with every files, but whenever it occurs, it gets reflected for every files.

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz `BufferedReader.readLine()` respects all linux, DOS/WIN and MacOS line ends, so no need to tranform using dos2unix.

Comment: @NitinNandankar how big is the file, or how long is the last line? Is this file open by any other process, for reading or writing?

Comment: @diginoise each file is has 12 lines and each line is has more than 10000 words

Comment: but the same file is getting processed successfully on someones system

Comment: @NitinNandankar, could you please print e.getMessage() on the catch clause ???

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz you can find stack trace in the above question

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz java.io.IOException: Input/output error

at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272) at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283) at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325) at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177) at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184) at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154) at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317) at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Buffe

Comment: could you maybe be running out of memory?¿ did you tried to execute the java with , for example:    `java -Xms256m -Xmx2048m` ?

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz i will try this..

Comment: Hey @NitinNandankar How is all? Did you finally managed how to solve it? Did you find new clues?

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz yes. Its hardware issue. Because of frequent connect-disconnect of hard-disk, IO error occurred.

Comment: hehehhe It seemed to be something like that. The memory issue should have been reported  (I was thinking on it yesterday when driving home). Happy to see you solved it!! . Plz, detail the solution in the answer and close it!! :) thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz i have tried it by reading files from a pendrive. At the start of reading lines from a file, i disconnected my pendirve and again reconnected it will the system. The solution is " i have changed my hardware."