# org.springframework.boot MD5 hash fails while compiling

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, md5

build.gradle contains the following plugin, but it started failing all of a sudden with gradle 7.4. what could be the issue here?

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
...
}

./gradlew test

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/bar/foo/build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.7.2']
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.
```

With --stacktrace

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.6.7']
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.exceptionOccurred(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:228)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:210)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyLegacyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:159)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.access$300(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:62)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$1$1.lambda$addLegacy$0(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:115)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyPlugins$0(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:144)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:144)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:117)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:360)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:378)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:359)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:360)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$2(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:408)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:270)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:408)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:389)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:359)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:760)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:151)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:328)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:33)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:50)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$3(VintageBuildModelController.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:227)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:238)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:226)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$10(StateTransitionController.java:201)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:197)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:89)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareToScheduleTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$prepareToScheduleTasks$2(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:134)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:227)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:238)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:226)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransition$9(StateTransitionController.java:187)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransition(StateTransitionController.java:183)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.prepareToScheduleTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:132)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$doScheduleAndRunTasks$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:89)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.doScheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:238)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:69
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:128)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:270)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:103)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.hash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultFileHasher.hash(DefaultFileHasher.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.snapshot(CachingFileHasher.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.hash(CachingFileHasher.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readLocation$6(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:171)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readSnapshotFromLocation$7(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:196)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess$StripedProducerGuard.guardByKey(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:219)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readSnapshotFromLocation$8(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:193)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readSnapshotFromLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:193)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readSnapshotFromLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:178)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:171)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.read(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$SnapshottingVisitor.visitCollection(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractOpaqueFileCollection.visitContents(AbstractOpaqueFileCollection.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:351)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.loadercache.DefaultClasspathHasher.hash(DefaultClasspathHasher.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.loadercache.DefaultClassLoaderCache.doGet(DefaultClassLoaderCache.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.loadercache.DefaultClassLoaderCache.get(DefaultClassLoaderCache.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.loadercache.DefaultClassLoaderCache.get(DefaultClassLoaderCache.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderScope.loader(DefaultClassLoaderScope.java:158)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderScope.loader(DefaultClassLoaderScope.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderScope.buildEffectiveLoaders(DefaultClassLoaderScope.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderScope.getLocalClassLoader(DefaultClassLoaderScope.java:133)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.lookup(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:167)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:142)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyLegacyPlugin$2(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:161)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:206)
        ... 155 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.doHash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.hash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:35)
        ... 184 more
```

Comment: Did you try to empty you gradle cache? Maybe some hickup of the locally cached data.

Comment: What's the stack trace (run Gradle with `--stacktrace`) of the failure?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have attached the stacktrace as well

Comment: @cyberbrain did empty cache, but didn't help. stopped working all of a sudden

Comment: @Rpj On the face of it, that looks like a Gradle bug. I would consider opening a Gradle issue, particularly if you can provide them with a way of reproducing the problem.

Comment: when you say `all of sudden`, does that mean it worked before with same setup? Also, can you please check if there is any changes recently in your filesystem e.g. permission changes .

Comment: Yes it was working earlier without any changes

Answer (score 1):

The "Input/output error" message typically indicates a hardware failure. You may have an issue on your hard disk and a file is not readable anymore.

It would explain why "it started failing all of a sudden".

Comment: As an example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920168/java-io-ioexception-input-output-error-at-last-line-of-a-file) with the same `java.io.IOException: Input/output error`. The comments confirm it was a hardware issue.

Comment: Is there a way to naildown what could be failing in the Mac hardware

Comment: @Rpj Did you try copying all files to another directory? It's a simple test to do. You will see if you get an error or not.

Comment: I did, there aren't any other issues. I removed the entire ~/.gradle folder as well didn't make a difference

Comment: @Rpj Did you try checking the filesystem? I'm not a Mac user but I'm sure there are some tools to do that.