# php cli prints error messages with expected output

Tags: php, command-line-interface, shebang, php-7.4

I am trying to write a simple CLI script, so I have the following code saved in a file named test.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php echo "Hello world of PHP CLI!"; ?>
```

When I try to execute the script by running the command `./test.php` I get the following output

> ./test.php: line 3: ?php: No such file or directory
>
> Hello world of PHP CLI!
>
> ./test.php: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
>
> ./test.php: line 5: `?>'

where I can see the expected output, but I also get some errors. Why am I seeing these errors and how can I fix this?

`php --version` output is

> PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2021 15:13:35) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
> The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: You seem to be confused between bash scripts and PHP scripts. What you've shown is half bash and half PHP. You executed it as a bash script, and the errors are because bash doesn't quite understand all your PHP syntax properly.

Comment: Read [the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php) to understand how to use the PHP CLI correctly.

Comment: Maybe i didn't use the terminology right, but I just followed this tutorial actually

http://www.php-cli.com/php-cli-tutorial.shtml

I can't understand what I might have done false

Comment: Also in the documentation it says the following " However, on Unix systems there's another way of using PHP for shell scripting: make the first line of the script start with #!/usr/bin/php (or whatever the path to your PHP CLI binary is if different). The rest of the file should contain normal PHP code within the usual PHP starting and end tags. Once the execution attributes of the file are set appropriately (e.g. chmod +x test), the script can be executed like any other shell or perl script: "

Comment: Ok I see. That makes a bit more sense then, thanks. I guess then maybe the path to the PHP executable is wrong? Or it doesn't like the -q?

Comment: No, I checked the executable already. I also tried without the -q option.

Comment: what does `which php` and `which env` output? That would determine the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line you put in the php file.  For example I use `#!/usr/bin/env php`. Also you would need to ensure that the line-endings in the php file are in the OS's format, which is usually the cause of the error you are receiving: Unix (`"/n"` as `LF`), OSX (`"/r"` as `CR`). You can use notepad++ in Windows or [VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82726/1144627) in Linux/OSX to convert the line endings.